# What is the best Battleship AI?

Tags: c#, .net, artificial-intelligence

Battleship!

Back in 2003 (when I was 17), I competed in a [Battleship AI](http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/t89846.html) coding competition.  Even though I lost that tournament, I had a lot of fun and learned a lot from it.

Now, I would like to resurrect this competition, in the search of the best battleship AI.

Here is [the framework, now hosted on Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/otac0n/battleship).

**The winner will be awarded +450 reputation!** The competition will be held starting on the **17th of November, 2009**.  No entries or edits later than zero-hour on the 17th will be accepted.  (Central Standard Time)
Submit your entries early, so you don't miss your opportunity!

*To keep this **OBJECTIVE**, please follow the spirit of the competition.*

**Rules of the game:**

1. The game is be played on a 10x10 grid.
2. Each competitor will place each of 5 ships (of lengths 2, 3, 3, 4, 5) on their grid.
3. No ships may overlap, but they may be adjacent.
4. The competitors then take turns firing single shots at their opponent.

   - A variation on the game allows firing multiple shots per volley, one for each surviving ship.
5. The opponent will notify the competitor if the shot sinks, hits, or misses.
6. Game play ends when all of the ships of any one player are sunk.

**Rules of the competition:**

1. The spirit of the competition is to find the best Battleship algorithm.
2. Anything that is deemed against the spirit of the competition will be grounds for disqualification.
3. Interfering with an opponent is against the spirit of the competition.
4. Multithreading may be used under the following restrictions:

   - No more than one thread may be running while it is not your turn. (Though, any number of threads may be in a "Suspended" state).
   - No thread may run at a priority other than "Normal".
   - Given the above two restrictions, you will be guaranteed at least 3 dedicated CPU cores during your turn.
5. A limit of 1 second of CPU time per game is allotted to each competitor on the primary thread.
6. Running out of time results in losing the current game.
7. Any unhandled exception will result in losing the current game.
8. Network access and disk access is allowed, but you may find the time restrictions fairly prohibitive.  However, a few set-up and tear-down methods have been added to alleviate the time strain.
9. Code should be posted on stack overflow as an answer, or, if too large, linked.
10. Max total size (un-compressed) of an entry is 1 MB.
11. Officially, .Net 2.0 / 3.5 is the only framework requirement.
12. Your entry must implement the IBattleshipOpponent interface.

**Scoring:**

1. Best 51 games out of 101 games is the winner of a match.
2. All competitors will play matched against each other, round-robin style.
3. The best half of the competitors will then play a double-elimination tournament to determine the winner.  (Smallest power of two that is greater than or equal to half, actually.)
4. I will be using the [TournamentApi](https://github.com/otac0n/tournaments) framework for the tournament.
5. The results will be posted here.
6. If you submit more than one entry, only your best-scoring entry is eligible for the double-elim.

Good luck! Have fun!

---

**EDIT 1:**
Thanks to [Freed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/190480/freed), who has found an error in the `Ship.IsValid` function.  It has been fixed.  Please download the updated version of the framework.

**EDIT 2:**
Since there has been significant interest in persisting stats to disk and such, I have added a few non-timed set-up and tear-down events that should provide the required functionality.  This is a **semi-breaking change**.  That is to say: the interface has been modified to add functions, but no body is required for them.  Please download the updated version of the framework.

**EDIT 3:**
Bug Fix 1: `GameWon` and `GameLost` were only getting called in the case of a time out.
Bug Fix 2: If an engine was timing out every game, the competition would never end.
Please download the updated version of the framework.

**EDIT 4:**
Tournament Results:

[image]

Comment: If the entry requires a large database, can it connect to it over net? Ie. can the entry make web service calls?

Comment: is there a size limit on the entries?

Comment: Yeah, but you have to make sure your download is fast.  You only have 1 second of time for your whole game.  (Of course, you could throw one game if it meant you could win the rest, I guess.)

Comment: @jherico:  I would like the code to be posted as a SO answer.  If that is not possible, then I guess, keep it under 1 meg.

Comment: @Steven: Also, I consulted Jeff Atwood just to see if it was appropriate.  Here is his response:  http://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/5203185621

Comment: BTW, reddited: http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/9ya6x/can_you_write_the_worlds_best_ai_for_battleship/

Comment: BTW, if the programs communicate moves through a TCP/IP intermediary, there'd be no reason to restrict entrants to C#

Comment: @John, just had a quick look at the framework, Ship.IsValid does not check that the X or Y coordinate small enough if Orientation is Vertical or Horizontal, respectively. Just thought you should know.

Comment: Code should be posted or linked from here.  Last-minute entries are fine, but I would prefer if code was posted early.  Any other code that specifically targets another engine is against the spirit of the competition.

Comment: What about the usual rule that ships cannot be placed adjacent to each other?

Comment: @Matt:  That is typically a rule for beginners, so that if two shots are next to each other, they are guaranteed to be from the same ship.  No such rule will be used here.

Comment: Sorry if it's in the api and I missed it but:
Do we get to persist state between matches?
(if so supply a utility function to do so so you can keep tabs on where we hit the file system)
Do we get informed of what round we are in (or at least round robin vs. playoffs)?
Do we get told who the opponent is (so we know if we meet them again in the later rounds)

Comment: @Shuggy:  Persisting data is permitted, but you have to write your own persistence layer.  Keep in mind that I will scrutinize heavily anything that uses IO or reflection.

Comment: do we know the opponent...
This is the thing that largely defines if it's worth caching state across rounds apart from count.

Comment: Any chance you could put the framework up on GitHub or something so we don't have to keep downloading a new zip file each time you make a change?  I don't think I'm getting the latest edits for set-up and tear-down.

Comment: some issues:
the game is biased in favour of the first player since they always get first shot in every match...
I'm not a fan of the friendly sanity checking and repeats in the competition logic. If you make an illegal move you should lose. If you make a stupid move you shouldn't be told you did!.

Comment: Also I would add taht, given the inevitable random component to these 50 games will not be enough to distinguish accurately between very good implementations. I would think that 501 or more may be necessary for a reasonable view on which is better.

Comment: A "peaceful" opponent that refuses to place ships causes the competition to hang. Not sure how much you care about people doing silly things like that. :)

Comment: In the real version, is it customary to tell your opponent what ship they hit? (e.g. "You sunk my battleship!") Without that bit of info, efficient targeting is not fun. Determining what ships are sunk seems like a variant of the packing problem. Good times!

Comment: @Joe: It doesn't hang, but it does take a while for the opponent's time to actually expire.  Also, the idea of the game is that you are a naval commander with only the sound of explosions to help you.  Hitting a ship and sinking a ship are both audible.  However, it is considered impossible to tell which ship was actually sunk just by sound.

Comment: @Shuggy:  In the original competition, every competitor beat the random engine in 100% of the games.  My engine was beating the random engine with more than 99.999% probability.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I second the motion to do a lot more games per match.  Doing 50 games is just flipping a coin.  I needed to do 1000 games to get any reasonable distinction between test algorithms.

Download [Dreadnought 1.2](http://keithandkatie.com/Dreadnought1.2.zip).

Strategies:

- keep track of all possible positions for ships that have >0 hits.  The list never gets bigger than ~30K so it can be kept exactly, unlike the list of all possible positions for all ships (which is very large).
- The GetShot algorithm has two parts, one which generates random shots and the other which
  tries to finish sinking an already hit ship.  We do random shots if there is a possible position (from the list above) in which all hit ships are sunk.  Otherwise, we try to finish sinking a ship by picking a location to shoot at which eliminates the most possible positions (weighted).
- For random shots, compute best location to shoot based on the likelihood of one of the unsunk ships overlapping the location.
- adaptive algorithm which places ships in locations where the opponent is statistically less likely to shoot.
- adaptive algorithm which prefers to shoot at locations where the opponent is statistically more likely to place his ships.
- place ships mostly not touching each other.

Comment: on my test machine (a ULV Celeron netbook) this code loses by timeout consistently. When I let it take all the time it wants it whips Simple (roughly 90% success rate). If you are relying heavily on the spec of the machine you're going to be running on to hit you timelimits you might want to give yourself some wiggle room...

Comment: Interesting...  It runs fine on the tournament machine.  However, a "perfect" engine would adapt to however much time it had already spent.

Answer (score 35):

Here is my entry! (The most naive solution possible)

"Random 1.1"

```
namespace Battleship
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
    using System.Drawing;

    public class RandomOpponent : IBattleshipOpponent
    {
        public string Name { get { return "Random"; } }
        public Version Version { get { return this.version; } }

        Random rand = new Random();
        Version version = new Version(1, 1);
        Size gameSize;

        public void NewGame(Size size, TimeSpan timeSpan)
        {
            this.gameSize = size;
        }

        public void PlaceShips(ReadOnlyCollection<Ship> ships)
        {
            foreach (Ship s in ships)
            {
                s.Place(
                    new Point(
                        rand.Next(this.gameSize.Width),
                        rand.Next(this.gameSize.Height)),
                    (ShipOrientation)rand.Next(2));
            }
        }

        public Point GetShot()
        {
            return new Point(
                rand.Next(this.gameSize.Width),
                rand.Next(this.gameSize.Height));
        }

        public void NewMatch(string opponent) { }
        public void OpponentShot(Point shot) { }
        public void ShotHit(Point shot, bool sunk) { }
        public void ShotMiss(Point shot) { }
        public void GameWon() { }
        public void GameLost() { }
        public void MatchOver() { }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, this answer is nice because it shows in a very concise form the API's you'd need to implement to compete... :)

Comment: Back when I built a similar project in my college Algorithms class I used random logic interlaced with some decision making. It was good sometimes!

Comment: This could attempt to place overlapping ships couldn't it?

Comment: Yes, but the engine will disallow this. It will then tell the AI to place them again, but this time, with a sterner voice. (Seen by `pop ax \ cmp ax, 1 \ je stern`)

Comment: Important note foranyone who, like me, figured they could easily beat this by remembering the previously placed shots and not repeating.
The framework will ignore repeats and give you another chance so long as your total time is less than the limit.
This is poor in my opinion, if someone messes up their algo they should be penalized...

Comment: @Shuggy, they are penalized, in time.

Answer (score 21):

Here's an opponent for people to play against:

- http://natekohl.net/files/FarnsworthOpponent.cs

Instead of using a fixed geometry-inspired strategy, I thought it would be interesting to attempt to **estimate the underlying probabilities** that any particular unexplored space holds a ship.

To do this right, you'd explore all possible configurations of ships that fit your current view of the world, and then compute probabilities based on those configurations.  You could think of it like exploring a tree:

[an expansion of possible battleship states http://natekohl.net/media/battleship-tree.png](http://natekohl.net/media/battleship-tree.png)

After considering all leaves of that tree that jive with what you know about the world *(e.g. ships can't overlap, all hit squares must be ships, etc.)* you can count how often ships occur at each unexplored position to estimate the likelihood that a ship is sitting there.

This can be visualized as a heat map, where hot spots are more likely to contain ships:

[a heat map of probabilities for each unexplored position http://natekohl.net/media/battleship-probs.png](http://natekohl.net/media/battleship-probs.png)

One thing I like about this Battleship competition is that the tree above is almost small enough to brute-force this kind of algorithm.  If there are ~150 possible positions for each of the 5 ships, that's 150<sup>5</sup> = 75 billion possibilities.  And that number only gets smaller, especially if you can eliminate whole ships.

The opponent that I linked to above doesn't explore the whole tree; 75 billion is still to big to get in under a second.  It does attempt to estimate these probabilities, though, with the help of a few heuristics.

Comment: So far, you are beating our only other full solution by about 67.7% to 32.3% :)

Comment: I'm definitely curious to see how a "probability approach" compares to a "geometric approach".  I've noticed that this probability opponent actually makes moves that follow the geometric patterns discussed in other answers.  It could be that using geometry is just as good, and a lot faster.  :)

Answer (score 11):

Not a fully fledged answer but there seems little point cluttering the real answers with code that is common.
I thus present some extensions/general classes in the spirit of open source.
If you use these then please change the namespace or trying to compile everything into one dll isn't going to work.

BoardView lets you easily work with an annotated board.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;

namespace Battleship.ShuggyCoUk
{
    public enum Compass
    {
        North,East,South,West
    }

    class Cell<T>
    {
        private readonly BoardView<T> view;
        public readonly int X;
        public readonly int Y;
        public T Data;
        public double Bias { get; set; }

        public Cell(BoardView<T> view, int x, int y) 
        { 
            this.view = view; this.X = x; this.Y = y; this.Bias = 1.0;  
        }

        public Point Location
        {
            get { return new Point(X, Y); }
        }

        public IEnumerable<U> FoldAll<U>(U acc, Func<Cell<T>, U, U> trip)
        {
            return new[] { Compass.North, Compass.East, Compass.South, Compass.West }
                .Select(x => FoldLine(x, acc, trip));
        }

        public U FoldLine<U>(Compass direction, U acc, Func<Cell<T>, U, U> trip)
        {
            var cell = this;
            while (true)
            {
                switch (direction)
                {
                    case Compass.North:
                        cell = cell.North; break;
                    case Compass.East:
                        cell = cell.East; break;
                    case Compass.South:
                        cell = cell.South; break;
                    case Compass.West:
                        cell = cell.West; break;
                }
                if (cell == null)
                    return acc;
                acc = trip(cell, acc);
            }
        }

        public Cell<T> North
        {
            get { return view.SafeLookup(X, Y - 1); }
        }

        public Cell<T> South
        {
            get { return view.SafeLookup(X, Y + 1); }
        }

        public Cell<T> East
        {
            get { return view.SafeLookup(X+1, Y); }
        }

        public Cell<T> West
        {
            get { return view.SafeLookup(X-1, Y); }
        }

        public IEnumerable<Cell<T>> Neighbours()
        {
            if (North != null)
                yield return North;
            if (South != null)
                yield return South;
            if (East != null)
                yield return East;
            if (West != null)
                yield return West;
        }
    }

    class BoardView<T>  : IEnumerable<Cell<T>>
    {
        public readonly Size Size;
        private readonly int Columns;
        private readonly int Rows;

        private Cell<T>[] history;

        public BoardView(Size size)
        {
            this.Size = size;
            Columns = size.Width;
            Rows = size.Height;
            this.history = new Cell<T>[Columns * Rows];
            for (int y = 0; y < Rows; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < Rows; x++)
                    history[x + y * Columns] = new Cell<T>(this, x, y);
            }
        }

        public T this[int x, int y]
        {
            get { return history[x + y * Columns].Data; }
            set { history[x + y * Columns].Data = value; }
        }

        public T this[Point p]
        {
            get { return history[SafeCalc(p.X, p.Y, true)].Data; }
            set { this.history[SafeCalc(p.X, p.Y, true)].Data = value; }
        }

        private int SafeCalc(int x, int y, bool throwIfIllegal)
        {
            if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= Columns || y >= Rows)
            {    if (throwIfIllegal)
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("["+x+","+y+"]");
                 else
                    return -1;
            }
            return x + y * Columns;
        }

        public void Set(T data)
        {
            foreach (var cell in this.history)
                cell.Data = data;
        }

        public Cell<T> SafeLookup(int x, int y)
        {
            int index = SafeCalc(x, y, false);
            if (index < 0)
                return null;
            return history[index];
        }

        #region IEnumerable<Cell<T>> Members

        public IEnumerator<Cell<T>> GetEnumerator()
        {
            foreach (var cell in this.history)
                yield return cell;
        }

        System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return this.GetEnumerator();
        }

        public BoardView<U> Transform<U>(Func<T, U> transform)
        {
            var result = new BoardView<U>(new Size(Columns, Rows));
            for (int y = 0; y < Rows; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < Columns; x++)
                {
                    result[x,y] = transform(this[x, y]);
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        public void WriteAsGrid(TextWriter w)
        {
            WriteAsGrid(w, "{0}");
        }

        public void WriteAsGrid(TextWriter w, string format)
        {
            WriteAsGrid(w, x => string.Format(format, x.Data));
        }

        public void WriteAsGrid(TextWriter w, Func<Cell<T>,string> perCell)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < Rows; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < Columns; x++)
                {
                    if (x != 0)
                        w.Write(",");
                    w.Write(perCell(this.SafeLookup(x, y)));
                }
                w.WriteLine();
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Some extensions, some of this duplicates functionality in the main framework but should really be done by you.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace Battleship.ShuggyCoUk
{
    public static class Extensions
    {        
        public static bool IsIn(this Point p, Size size)
        {
            return p.X >= 0 && p.Y >= 0 && p.X < size.Width && p.Y < size.Height;
        }

        public static bool IsLegal(this Ship ship,
            IEnumerable<Ship> ships, 
            Size board,
            Point location, 
            ShipOrientation direction)
        {
            var temp = new Ship(ship.Length);
            temp.Place(location, direction);
            if (!temp.GetAllLocations().All(p => p.IsIn(board)))
                return false;
            return ships.Where(s => s.IsPlaced).All(s => !s.ConflictsWith(temp));
        }

        public static bool IsTouching(this Point a, Point b)
        {
            return (a.X == b.X - 1 || a.X == b.X + 1) &&
                (a.Y == b.Y - 1 || a.Y == b.Y + 1);
        }

        public static bool IsTouching(this Ship ship,
            IEnumerable<Ship> ships,
            Point location,
            ShipOrientation direction)
        {
            var temp = new Ship(ship.Length);
            temp.Place(location, direction);
            var occupied = new HashSet<Point>(ships
                .Where(s => s.IsPlaced)
                .SelectMany(s => s.GetAllLocations()));
            if (temp.GetAllLocations().Any(p => occupied.Any(b => b.IsTouching(p))))
                return true;
            return false;
        }

        public static ReadOnlyCollection<Ship> MakeShips(params int[] lengths)
        {
            return new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<Ship>(
                lengths.Select(l => new Ship(l)).ToList());       
        }

        public static IEnumerable<T> Shuffle<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Rand rand)
        {
            T[] elements = source.ToArray();
            // Note i > 0 to avoid final pointless iteration
            for (int i = elements.Length - 1; i > 0; i--)
            {
                // Swap element "i" with a random earlier element it (or itself)
                int swapIndex = rand.Next(i + 1);
                T tmp = elements[i];
                elements[i] = elements[swapIndex];
                elements[swapIndex] = tmp;
            }
            // Lazily yield (avoiding aliasing issues etc)
            foreach (T element in elements)
            {
                yield return element;
            }
        }

        public static T RandomOrDefault<T>(this IEnumerable<T> things, Rand rand)
        {
            int count = things.Count();
            if (count == 0)
                return default(T);
            return things.ElementAt(rand.Next(count));
        }
    }
}
```

Something I end up using a lot.

```
enum OpponentsBoardState
{
    Unknown = 0,
    Miss,
    MustBeEmpty,        
    Hit,
}
```

Randomization.
Secure but testable, useful for testing.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;

namespace Battleship.ShuggyCoUk
{
    public class Rand
    {
        Random r;

        public Rand()
        {
            var rand = System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator.Create();
            byte[] b = new byte[4];
            rand.GetBytes(b);
            r = new Random(BitConverter.ToInt32(b, 0));
        }

        public int Next(int maxValue)
        {
            return r.Next(maxValue);
        }

        public double NextDouble(double maxValue)
        {
            return r.NextDouble() * maxValue;
        }

        public T Pick<T>(IEnumerable<T> things)
        {
            return things.ElementAt(Next(things.Count()));
        }

        public T PickBias<T>(Func<T, double> bias, IEnumerable<T> things)
        {
            double d = NextDouble(things.Sum(x => bias(x)));
            foreach (var x in things)
            {
                if (d < bias(x))
                    return x;
                d -= bias(x);                
            }
            throw new InvalidOperationException("fell off the end!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I don't have the time right now to write a full-fledged algorithm, but here's a thought: if your opponent placed ships randomly, wouldn't the placement probabilities be a simple distribution centered at (5.5,5.5)? For example, the placement possibilities for the battleship (5 units long) in the x dimension are here:

```
x    1 2 3 4 5  6  7 8 9 10
P(x) 2 4 6 8 10 10 8 6 4 2
```

The same calculations would be valid for y. The other ships would not have as steep of distributions, but your best guess is still the center. After that, the mathematical approach would be slowly radiating diagonals (perhaps with the length of the average ship, 17/5) out of the center. Ex:

```
...........
....x.x....
.....x.....
....x.x....
...........
```

Obviously some randomness would need to be added to the idea, but I think that purely mathematically that's the way to go.

Comment: Yes, indeed they would.  My old engine compensated for that.

Comment: Where I come from, slowly radiating diagonals out of the center is considered *cheating*.

Comment: If it's considered cheating, there's a pretty easy countermeasure. Avoid (x,y) where x=y. :)

Comment: I think he was alluding to card counting?  Which, in my opinion, is not cheating.

Answer (score 9):

Nothing that sophisticated but heres what I came up with. It beats the random opponent 99.9% of the time. Would be interested if anyone has any other little challenges like this, it was good fun.

```
namespace Battleship
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    public class AgentSmith : IBattleshipOpponent
    {        
        public string Name { get { return "Agent Smith"; } }
        public Version Version { get { return this.version; } }
        private Random rand = new Random();
        private Version version = new Version(2, 1);
        private Size gameSize;
        private enum Direction { Up, Down, Left, Right }
        private int MissCount;
        private Point?[] EndPoints = new Point?[2];
        private LinkedList<Point> HitShots = new LinkedList<Point>();
        private LinkedList<Point> Shots = new LinkedList<Point>();
        private List<Point> PatternShots = new List<Point>();
        private Direction ShotDirection = Direction.Up;
        private void NullOutTarget()
        {
            EndPoints = new Point?[2];
            MissCount = 0;
        }
        private void SetupPattern()
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < gameSize.Height; y++)
                for (int x = 0; x < gameSize.Width; x++)
                    if ((x + y) % 2 == 0) PatternShots.Add(new Point(x, y));
        }
        private bool InvalidShot(Point p)
        {
            bool InvalidShot = (Shots.Where(s => s.X == p.X && s.Y == p.Y).Any());
            if (p.X < 0 | p.Y<0) InvalidShot = true;
            if (p.X >= gameSize.Width | p.Y >= gameSize.Height) InvalidShot = true;
            return InvalidShot;
        }
        private Point FireDirectedShot(Direction? direction, Point p)
        {
            ShotDirection = (Direction)direction;
            switch (ShotDirection)
            {
                case Direction.Up: p.Y--; break;
                case Direction.Down: p.Y++; break;
                case Direction.Left: p.X--; break;
                case Direction.Right: p.X++; break;
            }
            return p;
        }
        private Point FireAroundPoint(Point p)
        {
            if (!InvalidShot(FireDirectedShot(ShotDirection,p)))
                return FireDirectedShot(ShotDirection, p);
            Point testShot = FireDirectedShot(Direction.Left, p);
            if (InvalidShot(testShot)) { testShot = FireDirectedShot(Direction.Right, p); }
            if (InvalidShot(testShot)) { testShot = FireDirectedShot(Direction.Up, p); }
            if (InvalidShot(testShot)) { testShot = FireDirectedShot(Direction.Down, p); }
            return testShot;
        }
        private Point FireRandomShot()
        {
            Point p;
            do
            {
                if (PatternShots.Count > 0)
                    PatternShots.Remove(p = PatternShots[rand.Next(PatternShots.Count)]);
                else do
                    {
                        p = FireAroundPoint(HitShots.First());
                        if (InvalidShot(p)) HitShots.RemoveFirst();
                    } while (InvalidShot(p) & HitShots.Count > 0);
            }
            while (InvalidShot(p));
            return p;
        }
        private Point FireTargettedShot()
        {
            Point p;
            do
            {
                p = FireAroundPoint(new Point(EndPoints[1].Value.X, EndPoints[1].Value.Y));
                if (InvalidShot(p) & EndPoints[1] != EndPoints[0])
                    EndPoints[1] = EndPoints[0];
                else if (InvalidShot(p)) NullOutTarget();
            } while (InvalidShot(p) & EndPoints[1] != null);
            if (InvalidShot(p)) p = FireRandomShot();
            return p;
        }
        private void ResetVars()
        {
            Shots.Clear();
            HitShots.Clear();
            PatternShots.Clear();
            MissCount = 0;
        }
        public void NewGame(Size size, TimeSpan timeSpan)
        {
            gameSize = size;
            ResetVars();
            SetupPattern();
        }
        public void PlaceShips(ReadOnlyCollection<Ship> ships)
        {
            foreach (Ship s in ships)
                s.Place(new Point(rand.Next(this.gameSize.Width), rand.Next(this.gameSize.Height)), (ShipOrientation)rand.Next(2));
        }
        public Point GetShot()
        {
            if (EndPoints[1] != null) Shots.AddLast(FireTargettedShot());
            else Shots.AddLast(FireRandomShot());
            return Shots.Last();
        }
        public void ShotHit(Point shot, bool sunk)
        {            
            HitShots.AddLast(shot);
            MissCount = 0;
            EndPoints[1] = shot;
            if (EndPoints[0] == null) EndPoints[0] = shot;
            if (sunk) NullOutTarget();
        }
        public void ShotMiss(Point shot)
        {
            if (++MissCount == 6) NullOutTarget();
        }
        public void GameWon() { }
        public void GameLost() { }
        public void NewMatch(string opponent) { }
        public void OpponentShot(Point shot) { }
        public void MatchOver() { }
    }
}
```

Slightly condensed to take up minimal space on here and still be readable.

Answer (score 6):

Some comments about the Competition Engine:

**NewGame parameters:**

If IBattleshipOpponent::NewGame is intended for pre-game setup and takes a boardsize, it should also take a list of ships and their respective sizes.  It makes no sense to allow for variable board-size without allowing for variable ship configurations.

**Ships are sealed:**

I don't see any reason why class Ship is sealed.  Among other basic things, I would like Ships to have a Name, so I can output messages like *("You sunk my {0}", ship.Name);*.  I have other extensions in mind too, so I think Ship should be inheritable.

**Time Limits:**

While the time limit of 1 second makes sense for a tournament rule, it totally messes with debugging.  BattleshipCompetition should have an easy setting to ignore time-violations to aid with development/debugging.  I would also suggest investigating System.Diagnostics.Process::UserProcessorTime / Privileged ProcessorTime / TotalProcessorTime for a more accurate view of how much time is being used.

**Sunk Ships:**

The current API informs you when you've sunk an oppenent's ship:

```
ShotHit(Point shot, bool sunk);
```

but not **which** ship you sunk!  I consider it part of the human-Battleship rules that you are required to declare "You sunk my Battleship!" (or destroyer, or sub, etc).

This is especially critical when an AI is trying to flush out ships that butt-up against each other.   I'd like to request an API change to:

```
ShotHit(Point shot, Ship ship);
```

If *ship* is non-null, it implies that the shot was a sinking-shot, and you know which ship you sunk, and how long it was.  If the shot was a non-sinking shot, then ship is null, and you have no further information.

Comment: Please post code samples if you think that the timing can be done more accurately.  I don't want to change the rules too much right now.

Comment: Also, the ship sizes are passed in during the PlaceShips() which is run exactly once per game and can also be used as a set-up phase.  Please feel free to unseal the ship for your own testing, but I plan on using the sealed one for the tournament.

Comment: BUG: @John Gietzen:  I have determined that PlaceShips is NOT run exactly once per game (as you stated).  If a player places their ships incorrectly (as the RandomOpponent often does), then PlaceShips is called repeatedly, without an intervening NewGame call.

Comment: I don't think that's a bug in the software, I think that's a bug in the "spec" or more correctly in his comment here.

Comment: @abelenky: Well, right.  That is: if you screw up, it calls it untill you act right.

Comment: I always considered it a strategy to place two ships in an L configuration to make my opponent think they had sunk a battleship when in fact they hadn't. I was never under the impression you had to declare which boat was sunk.

Comment: You don't have to declare.  Check the rules from the original pencil-and-paer game.

Comment: The rules from hasbro say you do - http://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/BattleShip_%282002%29.PDF

Comment: @DJ:  I'm going by the original pen-and-paper rules.  Remember that Hasbro is a toy company and that this game predates Hasbro.

Answer (score 4):

CrossFire updated.
I know it can't compete with Farnsworth or Dreadnought but it is a lot faster than the latter and simple to play with in case anyone wants to try.
This relies on the current state of my libraries,included here to make it easy to use.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace Battleship.ShuggyCoUk
{
    public class Simple : IBattleshipOpponent
    {
        BoardView<OpponentsBoardState> opponentsBoard = new BoardView<OpponentsBoardState>(new Size(10,10));
        Rand rand = new Rand();
        int gridOddEven;
        Size size;

        public string Name { get { return "Simple"; } }

        public Version Version { get { return new Version(2, 1); }}

        public void NewMatch(string opponent) {}

        public void NewGame(System.Drawing.Size size, TimeSpan timeSpan)
        {
            this.size = size;
            this.opponentsBoard = new BoardView<OpponentsBoardState>(size);
            this.gridOddEven = rand.Pick(new[] { 0, 1 });
        }

        public void PlaceShips(System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<Ship> ships)
        {
            BoardView<bool> board = new BoardView<bool>(size);
            var AllOrientations = new[] {
                ShipOrientation.Horizontal,
                ShipOrientation.Vertical };

            foreach (var ship in ships)
            {
                int avoidTouching = 3;
                while (!ship.IsPlaced)
                {
                    var l = rand.Pick(board.Select(c => c.Location));
                    var o = rand.Pick(AllOrientations);
                    if (ship.IsLegal(ships, size, l, o))
                    {
                        if (ship.IsTouching(ships, l, o)&& --avoidTouching > 0)
                            continue;
                        ship.Place(l, o);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        protected virtual Point PickWhenNoTargets()
        {
            return rand.PickBias(x => x.Bias,
                opponentsBoard
                // nothing 1 in size
                .Where(c => (c.Location.X + c.Location.Y) % 2 == gridOddEven)
                .Where(c => c.Data == OpponentsBoardState.Unknown))
                .Location;
        }

        private int SumLine(Cell<OpponentsBoardState> c, int acc)
        {
            if (acc >= 0)
                return acc;
            if (c.Data == OpponentsBoardState.Hit)
                return acc - 1;
            return -acc;
        }

        public System.Drawing.Point GetShot()
        {
            var targets = opponentsBoard
                .Where(c => c.Data == OpponentsBoardState.Hit)
                .SelectMany(c => c.Neighbours())
                .Where(c => c.Data == OpponentsBoardState.Unknown)
                .ToList();
            if (targets.Count > 1)
            {
                var lines = targets.Where(
                    x => x.FoldAll(-1, SumLine).Select(r => Math.Abs(r) - 1).Max() > 1).ToList();
                if (lines.Count > 0)
                    targets = lines;
            }
            var target = targets.RandomOrDefault(rand);
            if (target == null)
                return PickWhenNoTargets();
            return target.Location;
        }

        public void OpponentShot(System.Drawing.Point shot)
        {
        }

        public void ShotHit(Point shot, bool sunk)
        {
            opponentsBoard[shot] = OpponentsBoardState.Hit;
            Debug(shot, sunk);
        }

        public void ShotMiss(Point shot)
        {
            opponentsBoard[shot] = OpponentsBoardState.Miss;
            Debug(shot, false);
        }

        public const bool DebugEnabled = false;

        public void Debug(Point shot, bool sunk)
        {
            if (!DebugEnabled)
                return;
            opponentsBoard.WriteAsGrid(
                Console.Out,
                x =>
                {
                    string t;
                    switch (x.Data)
                    {
                        case OpponentsBoardState.Unknown:
                            return " ";
                        case OpponentsBoardState.Miss:
                            t = "m";
                            break;
                        case OpponentsBoardState.MustBeEmpty:
                            t = "/";
                            break;
                        case OpponentsBoardState.Hit:
                            t = "x";
                            break;
                        default:
                            t = "?";
                            break;
                    }
                    if (x.Location == shot)
                        t = t.ToUpper();
                    return t;
                });
            if (sunk)
                Console.WriteLine("sunk!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public void GameWon()
        {
        }

        public void GameLost()
        {
        }

        public void MatchOver()
        {
        }

        #region Library code
        enum OpponentsBoardState
        {
            Unknown = 0,
            Miss,
            MustBeEmpty,
            Hit,
        }

        public enum Compass
        {
            North, East, South, West
        }

        class Cell<T>
        {
            private readonly BoardView<T> view;
            public readonly int X;
            public readonly int Y;
            public T Data;
            public double Bias { get; set; }

            public Cell(BoardView<T> view, int x, int y)
            {
                this.view = view; this.X = x; this.Y = y; this.Bias = 1.0;
            }

            public Point Location
            {
                get { return new Point(X, Y); }
            }

            public IEnumerable<U> FoldAll<U>(U acc, Func<Cell<T>, U, U> trip)
            {
                return new[] { Compass.North, Compass.East, Compass.South, Compass.West }
                    .Select(x => FoldLine(x, acc, trip));
            }

            public U FoldLine<U>(Compass direction, U acc, Func<Cell<T>, U, U> trip)
            {
                var cell = this;
                while (true)
                {
                    switch (direction)
                    {
                        case Compass.North:
                            cell = cell.North; break;
                        case Compass.East:
                            cell = cell.East; break;
                        case Compass.South:
                            cell = cell.South; break;
                        case Compass.West:
                            cell = cell.West; break;
                    }
                    if (cell == null)
                        return acc;
                    acc = trip(cell, acc);
                }
            }

            public Cell<T> North
            {
                get { return view.SafeLookup(X, Y - 1); }
            }

            public Cell<T> South
            {
                get { return view.SafeLookup(X, Y + 1); }
            }

            public Cell<T> East
            {
                get { return view.SafeLookup(X + 1, Y); }
            }

            public Cell<T> West
            {
                get { return view.SafeLookup(X - 1, Y); }
            }

            public IEnumerable<Cell<T>> Neighbours()
            {
                if (North != null)
                    yield return North;
                if (South != null)
                    yield return South;
                if (East != null)
                    yield return East;
                if (West != null)
                    yield return West;
            }
        }

        class BoardView<T> : IEnumerable<Cell<T>>
        {
            public readonly Size Size;
            private readonly int Columns;
            private readonly int Rows;

            private Cell<T>[] history;

            public BoardView(Size size)
            {
                this.Size = size;
                Columns = size.Width;
                Rows = size.Height;
                this.history = new Cell<T>[Columns * Rows];
                for (int y = 0; y < Rows; y++)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < Rows; x++)
                        history[x + y * Columns] = new Cell<T>(this, x, y);
                }
            }

            public T this[int x, int y]
            {
                get { return history[x + y * Columns].Data; }
                set { history[x + y * Columns].Data = value; }
            }

            public T this[Point p]
            {
                get { return history[SafeCalc(p.X, p.Y, true)].Data; }
                set { this.history[SafeCalc(p.X, p.Y, true)].Data = value; }
            }

            private int SafeCalc(int x, int y, bool throwIfIllegal)
            {
                if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= Columns || y >= Rows)
                {
                    if (throwIfIllegal)
                        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("[" + x + "," + y + "]");
                    else
                        return -1;
                }
                return x + y * Columns;
            }

            public void Set(T data)
            {
                foreach (var cell in this.history)
                    cell.Data = data;
            }

            public Cell<T> SafeLookup(int x, int y)
            {
                int index = SafeCalc(x, y, false);
                if (index < 0)
                    return null;
                return history[index];
            }

            #region IEnumerable<Cell<T>> Members

            public IEnumerator<Cell<T>> GetEnumerator()
            {
                foreach (var cell in this.history)
                    yield return cell;
            }

            System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
            {
                return this.GetEnumerator();
            }

            public BoardView<U> Transform<U>(Func<T, U> transform)
            {
                var result = new BoardView<U>(new Size(Columns, Rows));
                for (int y = 0; y < Rows; y++)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < Columns; x++)
                    {
                        result[x, y] = transform(this[x, y]);
                    }
                }
                return result;
            }

            public void WriteAsGrid(TextWriter w)
            {
                WriteAsGrid(w, "{0}");
            }

            public void WriteAsGrid(TextWriter w, string format)
            {
                WriteAsGrid(w, x => string.Format(format, x.Data));
            }

            public void WriteAsGrid(TextWriter w, Func<Cell<T>, string> perCell)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < Rows; y++)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < Columns; x++)
                    {
                        if (x != 0)
                            w.Write(",");
                        w.Write(perCell(this.SafeLookup(x, y)));
                    }
                    w.WriteLine();
                }
            }

            #endregion
        }

        public class Rand
        {
            Random r;

            public Rand()
            {
                var rand = System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator.Create();
                byte[] b = new byte[4];
                rand.GetBytes(b);
                r = new Random(BitConverter.ToInt32(b, 0));
            }

            public int Next(int maxValue)
            {
                return r.Next(maxValue);
            }

            public double NextDouble(double maxValue)
            {
                return r.NextDouble() * maxValue;
            }

            public T Pick<T>(IEnumerable<T> things)
            {
                return things.ElementAt(Next(things.Count()));
            }

            public T PickBias<T>(Func<T, double> bias, IEnumerable<T> things)
            {
                double d = NextDouble(things.Sum(x => bias(x)));
                foreach (var x in things)
                {
                    if (d < bias(x))
                        return x;
                    d -= bias(x);
                }
                throw new InvalidOperationException("fell off the end!");
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }

    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static bool IsIn(this Point p, Size size)
        {
            return p.X >= 0 && p.Y >= 0 && p.X < size.Width && p.Y < size.Height;
        }

        public static bool IsLegal(this Ship ship,
            IEnumerable<Ship> ships,
            Size board,
            Point location,
            ShipOrientation direction)
        {
            var temp = new Ship(ship.Length);
            temp.Place(location, direction);
            if (!temp.GetAllLocations().All(p => p.IsIn(board)))
                return false;
            return ships.Where(s => s.IsPlaced).All(s => !s.ConflictsWith(temp));
        }

        public static bool IsTouching(this Point a, Point b)
        {
            return (a.X == b.X - 1 || a.X == b.X + 1) &&
                (a.Y == b.Y - 1 || a.Y == b.Y + 1);
        }

        public static bool IsTouching(this Ship ship,
            IEnumerable<Ship> ships,
            Point location,
            ShipOrientation direction)
        {
            var temp = new Ship(ship.Length);
            temp.Place(location, direction);
            var occupied = new HashSet<Point>(ships
                .Where(s => s.IsPlaced)
                .SelectMany(s => s.GetAllLocations()));
            if (temp.GetAllLocations().Any(p => occupied.Any(b => b.IsTouching(p))))
                return true;
            return false;
        }

        public static ReadOnlyCollection<Ship> MakeShips(params int[] lengths)
        {
            return new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<Ship>(
                lengths.Select(l => new Ship(l)).ToList());
        }

        public static IEnumerable<T> Shuffle<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Battleship.ShuggyCoUk.Simple.Rand rand)
        {
            T[] elements = source.ToArray();
            // Note i > 0 to avoid final pointless iteration
            for (int i = elements.Length - 1; i > 0; i--)
            {
                // Swap element "i" with a random earlier element it (or itself)
                int swapIndex = rand.Next(i + 1);
                T tmp = elements[i];
                elements[i] = elements[swapIndex];
                elements[swapIndex] = tmp;
            }
            // Lazily yield (avoiding aliasing issues etc)
            foreach (T element in elements)
            {
                yield return element;
            }
        }

        public static T RandomOrDefault<T>(this IEnumerable<T> things, Battleship.ShuggyCoUk.Simple.Rand rand)
        {
            int count = things.Count();
            if (count == 0)
                return default(T);
            return things.ElementAt(rand.Next(count));
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 4):

I'm not going to be able to participate, but here's the algorithm I'd implement if I had time:

First, when I detect a hit I do not pursue the rest of the ship immediately - I build a table of ship locations and figure out whether I've hit all five at least once before starting to fully sink them. (Note that this is a bad policy for the multiple shot variant - see comments)

1. Hit the center (see final note below - 'center' is just a convenience for description)
2. Hit the spot 4 to the right of the center
3. Hit the spot 1 down and one to the right of the center
4. Hit the spot four to the right of the previous hit
5. Continue in that pattern (should end up with diagonal lines separated by 3 spaces filling the board)  This should hit all 4 and 5 length boats, and a statistically large number of 3 and 2 boats.
6. Start randomly hitting spots inbetween the diagonals, this will catch the 2 and 3 length boats that haven't already been noticed.

Once I have detected 5 hits, I'd determine if the 5 hits are on separate boats.  This is relatively easy by making a few more shots near locations where two hits are on the same horizontal or vertical line and are within 5 locations of each other (might be two hits on the same boat).  If they are separate boats then continue to sink all the ships.  If they are found to be the same boat, continue the filling patterns above until all 5 boats are located.

This algorithm is a simple filling algorithm.  The key features are that it does not waste time sinking ships it knows about when there are still ships it's unaware of, and it doesn't use an inefficient filling pattern (ie, a fully random pattern would be wasteful).

**Final notes:**

A) "Center" is a random starting point on the board.  This eliminates the primary weakness of this algorithm.
B) While the description indicates drawing diagonals immediately from the start, ideally the algorithm merely shoots at 'random' locations that are along those diagonals.  This helps prevent the competitor from timing how long until their ships are hit by predictable patterns.

This describes a 'perfect' algorithm in that it'll get all the ships in under (9x9)/2+10 shots.

**However, it can be improved significantly:**

Once a ship is hit, identify its size before doing the 'internal' diagonal lines.  You may have found the 2 ship, in which case the internal diagonals can be simplified to find the 3 size ships more quickly.

Identify stages in the game and act accordingly.  This algorithm may be good up to a certain point in the game, but other algorithms may yield better benefits as part of the endgame.  Also, if the other player is very close to defeating you, another algorithm might work better - for instance a high risk algorithm might fail more often, but when it works it works quickly and you may beat your opponent who is closer to winning than you.

Identify the play style of the competitor - it may give you clues as to how they plan ship placement (ie, chances are good that their own algorithm most quickly identifies how they place their own ships - if the only tool you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail)

-Adam

Comment: The strategy of waiting to sink ships until all are found depends heavily on the one-shot-per-turn variation. Under the (number of surviving ships)-shots-per-turn version, it is advantageous to sink ships as quickly as possible so as to slow your opponent.

Answer (score 4):

This is about the best that I could put together in my free time, which is about non-existent. There is some game and match tallying stats going on, as I set up the main function to loop and continuously run the BattleshipCompetition until I pressed a key.

```
namespace Battleship
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;

    public class BP7 : IBattleshipOpponent
    {
        public string Name { get { return "BP7"; } }
        public Version Version { get { return this.version; } }

        Random rand = new Random();
        Version version = new Version(0, 7);
        Size gameSize;
        List<Point> scanShots;
        List<NextShot> nextShots;
        int wins, losses;
        int totalWins = 0;
        int totalLosses = 0;
        int maxWins = 0;
        int maxLosses = 0;
        int matchWins = 0;
        int matchLosses = 0;

        public enum Direction { VERTICAL = -1, UNKNOWN = 0, HORIZONTAL = 1 };
        Direction hitDirection, lastShotDirection;

        enum ShotResult { UNKNOWN, MISS, HIT };
        ShotResult[,] board;

        public struct NextShot
        {
            public Point point;
            public Direction direction;
            public NextShot(Point p, Direction d)
            {
                point = p;
                direction = d;
            }
        }

        public struct ScanShot
        {
            public Point point;
            public int openSpaces;
            public ScanShot(Point p, int o)
            {
                point = p;
                openSpaces = o;
            }
        }

        public void NewGame(Size size, TimeSpan timeSpan)
        {
            this.gameSize = size;
            scanShots = new List<Point>();
            nextShots = new List<NextShot>();
            fillScanShots();
            hitDirection = Direction.UNKNOWN;
            board = new ShotResult[size.Width, size.Height];
        }

        private void fillScanShots()
        {
            int x;
            for (x = 0; x < gameSize.Width - 1; x++)
            {
                scanShots.Add(new Point(x, x));
            }

            if (gameSize.Width == 10)
            {
                for (x = 0; x < 3; x++)
                {
                    scanShots.Add(new Point(9 - x, x));
                    scanShots.Add(new Point(x, 9 - x));
                }
            }
        }

        public void PlaceShips(System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<Ship> ships)
        {
            foreach (Ship s in ships)
            {
                s.Place(
                    new Point(
                        rand.Next(this.gameSize.Width),
                        rand.Next(this.gameSize.Height)),
                    (ShipOrientation)rand.Next(2));
            }
        }

        public Point GetShot()
        {
            Point shot;

            if (this.nextShots.Count > 0)
            {
                if (hitDirection != Direction.UNKNOWN)
                {
                    if (hitDirection == Direction.HORIZONTAL)
                    {
                        this.nextShots = this.nextShots.OrderByDescending(x => x.direction).ToList();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.nextShots = this.nextShots.OrderBy(x => x.direction).ToList();
                    }
                }

                shot = this.nextShots.First().point;
                lastShotDirection = this.nextShots.First().direction;
                this.nextShots.RemoveAt(0);
                return shot;
            }

            List<ScanShot> scanShots = new List<ScanShot>();
            for (int x = 0; x < gameSize.Width; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < gameSize.Height; y++)
                {
                    if (board[x, y] == ShotResult.UNKNOWN)
                    {
                        scanShots.Add(new ScanShot(new Point(x, y), OpenSpaces(x, y)));
                    }
                }
            }
            scanShots = scanShots.OrderByDescending(x => x.openSpaces).ToList();
            int maxOpenSpaces = scanShots.FirstOrDefault().openSpaces;

            List<ScanShot> scanShots2 = new List<ScanShot>();
            scanShots2 = scanShots.Where(x => x.openSpaces == maxOpenSpaces).ToList();
            shot = scanShots2[rand.Next(scanShots2.Count())].point;

            return shot;
        }

        int OpenSpaces(int x, int y)
        {
            int ctr = 0;
            Point p;

            // spaces to the left
            p = new Point(x - 1, y);
            while (p.X >= 0 && board[p.X, p.Y] == ShotResult.UNKNOWN)
            {
                ctr++;
                p.X--;
            }

            // spaces to the right
            p = new Point(x + 1, y);
            while (p.X < gameSize.Width && board[p.X, p.Y] == ShotResult.UNKNOWN)
            {
                ctr++;
                p.X++;
            }

            // spaces to the top
            p = new Point(x, y - 1);
            while (p.Y >= 0 && board[p.X, p.Y] == ShotResult.UNKNOWN)
            {
                ctr++;
                p.Y--;
            }

            // spaces to the bottom
            p = new Point(x, y + 1);
            while (p.Y < gameSize.Height && board[p.X, p.Y] == ShotResult.UNKNOWN)
            {
                ctr++;
                p.Y++;
            }

            return ctr;
        }

        public void NewMatch(string opponenet)
        {
            wins = 0;
            losses = 0;
        }

        public void OpponentShot(Point shot) { }

        public void ShotHit(Point shot, bool sunk)
        {
            board[shot.X, shot.Y] = ShotResult.HIT;

            if (!sunk)
            {
                hitDirection = lastShotDirection;
                if (shot.X != 0)
                {
                    this.nextShots.Add(new NextShot(new Point(shot.X - 1, shot.Y), Direction.HORIZONTAL));
                }

                if (shot.Y != 0)
                {
                    this.nextShots.Add(new NextShot(new Point(shot.X, shot.Y - 1), Direction.VERTICAL));
                }

                if (shot.X != this.gameSize.Width - 1)
                {
                    this.nextShots.Add(new NextShot(new Point(shot.X + 1, shot.Y), Direction.HORIZONTAL));
                }

                if (shot.Y != this.gameSize.Height - 1)
                {
                    this.nextShots.Add(new NextShot(new Point(shot.X, shot.Y + 1), Direction.VERTICAL));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                hitDirection = Direction.UNKNOWN;
                this.nextShots.Clear();     // so now this works like gangbusters ?!?!?!?!?!?!?!?!?
            }
        }

        public void ShotMiss(Point shot)
        {
            board[shot.X, shot.Y] = ShotResult.MISS;
        }

        public void GameWon()
        {
            wins++;
        }

        public void GameLost()
        {
            losses++;
        }

        public void MatchOver()
        {
            if (wins > maxWins)
            {
                maxWins = wins;
            }

            if (losses > maxLosses)
            {
                maxLosses = losses;
            }

            totalWins += wins;
            totalLosses += losses;

            if (wins >= 51)
            {
                matchWins++;
            }
            else
            {
                matchLosses++;
            }
        }

        public void FinalStats()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Games won: " + totalWins.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Games lost: " + totalLosses.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Game winning percentage: " + (totalWins * 1.0 / (totalWins + totalLosses)).ToString("P"));
            Console.WriteLine("Game losing percentage: " + (totalLosses * 1.0 / (totalWins + totalLosses)).ToString("P"));
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Matches won: " + matchWins.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Matches lost: " + matchLosses.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Match winning percentage: " + (matchWins * 1.0 / (matchWins + matchLosses)).ToString("P"));
            Console.WriteLine("Match losing percentage: " + (matchLosses * 1.0 / (matchWins + matchLosses)).ToString("P"));
            Console.WriteLine("Match games won high: " + maxWins.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Match games lost high: " + maxLosses.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

This logic is the closest that I had to beating Dreadnought, winning about 41% of the individual games. (It actually did win one match by a count of 52 to 49.) Oddly enough, this class does not do as well against FarnsworthOpponent as an earlier version that was much less advanced.

Answer (score 4):

My computer is being repaired by dell right now, but this is where i was at last week:

```
namespace Battleship
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;

    public class BSKiller4 : OpponentExtended, IBattleshipOpponent
    {
        public string Name { get { return "BSKiller4"; } }
        public Version Version { get { return this.version; } }

        public bool showBoard = false;

        Random rand = new Random();
        Version version = new Version(0, 4);
        Size gameSize;

        List<Point> nextShots;
        Queue<Point> scanShots;

        char[,] board;

        private void printBoard()
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            for (int y = 0; y < this.gameSize.Height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < this.gameSize.Width; x++)
                {
                    Console.Write(this.board[x, y]);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public void NewGame(Size size, TimeSpan timeSpan)
        {
            this.gameSize = size;
            board = new char[size.Width, size.Height];
            this.nextShots = new List<Point>();
            this.scanShots = new Queue<Point>();
            fillScanShots();
            initializeBoard();
        }

        private void initializeBoard()
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < this.gameSize.Height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < this.gameSize.Width; x++)
                {
                    this.board[x, y] = 'O';
                }
            }
        }

        private void fillScanShots()
        {
            int x, y;
            int num = gameSize.Width * gameSize.Height;
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                for (int i = j; i < num; i += 3)
                {
                    x = i % gameSize.Width;
                    y = i / gameSize.Height;
                    scanShots.Enqueue(new Point(x, y));
                }
            }
        }

        public void PlaceShips(ReadOnlyCollection<Ship> ships)
        {
            foreach (Ship s in ships)
            {
                s.Place(new Point(
                        rand.Next(this.gameSize.Width),
                        rand.Next(this.gameSize.Height)),
                        (ShipOrientation)rand.Next(2));
            }
        }

        public Point GetShot()
        {
            if (showBoard) printBoard();
            Point shot;

            shot = findShotRun();
            if (shot.X != -1)
            {
                return shot;
            }

            if (this.nextShots.Count > 0)
            {
                shot = this.nextShots[0];
                this.nextShots.RemoveAt(0);
            }
            else
            {
                shot = this.scanShots.Dequeue();
            }

            return shot;
        }

        public void ShotHit(Point shot, bool sunk)
        {
            this.board[shot.X, shot.Y] = 'H';
            if (!sunk)
            {
                addToNextShots(new Point(shot.X - 1, shot.Y));
                addToNextShots(new Point(shot.X, shot.Y + 1));
                addToNextShots(new Point(shot.X + 1, shot.Y));
                addToNextShots(new Point(shot.X, shot.Y - 1));
            }
            else
            {
                this.nextShots.Clear();
            }
        }



        private Point findShotRun()
        {
            int run_forward_horizontal = 0;
            int run_backward_horizontal = 0;
            int run_forward_vertical = 0;
            int run_backward_vertical = 0;

            List<shotPossibilities> possible = new List<shotPossibilities>(5);

            // this only works if width = height for the board;
            for (int y = 0; y < this.gameSize.Height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < this.gameSize.Width; x++)
                {
                    // forward horiz
                    if (this.board[x, y] == 'M')
                    {
                        run_forward_horizontal = 0;
                    }
                    else if (this.board[x, y] == 'O')
                    {
                        if (run_forward_horizontal >= 2)
                        {
                            possible.Add(
                                new shotPossibilities(
                                    run_forward_horizontal,
                                    new Point(x, y),
                                    true));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            run_forward_horizontal = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        run_forward_horizontal++;
                    }

                    // forward vertical
                    if (this.board[y, x] == 'M')
                    {
                        run_forward_vertical = 0;
                    }
                    else if (this.board[y, x] == 'O')
                    {
                        if (run_forward_vertical >= 2)
                        {
                            possible.Add(
                                new shotPossibilities(
                                    run_forward_vertical,
                                    new Point(y, x),
                                    false));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            run_forward_vertical = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        run_forward_vertical++;
                    }


                    // backward horiz
                    if (this.board[this.gameSize.Width - x - 1, y] == 'M')
                    {
                        run_backward_horizontal = 0;
                    }
                    else if (this.board[this.gameSize.Width - x - 1, y] == 'O')
                    {
                        if (run_backward_horizontal >= 2)
                        {
                            possible.Add(
                                new shotPossibilities(
                                    run_backward_horizontal,
                                    new Point(this.gameSize.Width - x - 1, y),
                                    true));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            run_backward_horizontal = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        run_backward_horizontal++;
                    }


                    // backward vertical
                    if (this.board[y, this.gameSize.Height - x - 1] == 'M')
                    {
                        run_backward_vertical = 0;
                    }
                    else if (this.board[y, this.gameSize.Height - x - 1] == 'O')
                    {
                        if (run_backward_vertical >= 2)
                        {
                            possible.Add(
                                new shotPossibilities(
                                    run_backward_vertical,
                                    new Point(y, this.gameSize.Height - x - 1),
                                    false));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            run_backward_vertical = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        run_backward_vertical++;
                    }

                }

                run_forward_horizontal = 0;
                run_backward_horizontal = 0;
                run_forward_vertical = 0;
                run_backward_vertical = 0;
            }
            Point shot;

            if (possible.Count > 0)
            {
                shotPossibilities shotp = possible.OrderByDescending(a => a.run).First();
                //this.nextShots.Clear();
                shot = shotp.shot;
                //if (shotp.isHorizontal)
                //{
                //    this.nextShots.RemoveAll(p => p.X != shot.X);
                //}
                //else
                //{
                //    this.nextShots.RemoveAll(p => p.Y != shot.Y);
                //}
            }
            else
            {
                shot = new Point(-1, -1);
            }

            return shot;
        }

        private void addToNextShots(Point p)
        {
            if (!this.nextShots.Contains(p) &&
                p.X >= 0 &&
                p.X < this.gameSize.Width &&
                p.Y >= 0 &&
                p.Y < this.gameSize.Height)
            {
                if (this.board[p.X, p.Y] == 'O')
                {
                    this.nextShots.Add(p);
                }
            }
        }

        public void GameWon()
        {
            this.GameWins++;
        }

        public void NewMatch(string opponent)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5);
            this.rand = new Random(System.Environment.TickCount);
        }
        public void OpponentShot(Point shot) { }
        public void ShotMiss(Point shot)
        {
            this.board[shot.X, shot.Y] = 'M';
        }
        public void GameLost()
        {
            if (showBoard) Console.WriteLine("-----Game Over-----");
        }
        public void MatchOver() { }
    }


    public class OpponentExtended
    {
        public int GameWins { get; set; }
        public int MatchWins { get; set; }
        public OpponentExtended() { }
    }

    public class shotPossibilities
    {
        public shotPossibilities(int r, Point s, bool h)
        {
            this.run = r;
            this.shot = s;
            this.isHorizontal = h;
        }
        public int run { get; set; }
        public Point shot { get; set; }
        public bool isHorizontal { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Congrats on the silver.

Do you mind describing your algorithm in words? It would be interesting to know about.

Answer (score 3):

If you are brute forcing your analysis then you may find the mechanics of the supplied RandomOpponent highly inefficient. It allows itself to reselect already targeted locations and lets the framework force it to repeat till it hits one it hasn't touched yet or the timelimit per move expires.

This opponent has similar behaviour (the effective placement distribution is the same) it just does the sanity checking itself and only consumes one random number generation per call (amortized)).

This uses the classes in my extensions/library answer and I only supply the key methods/state.

Shuffle is lifted from [Jon Skeet's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287567/c-is-using-random-and-orderby-a-good-shuffle-algorithm)

```
class WellBehavedRandomOpponent : IBattleShipOpponent
{
    Rand rand = new Rand();
    List<Point> guesses;
    int nextGuess = 0;

    public void PlaceShips(IEnumerable<Ship> ships)
    {
        BoardView<bool> board = new BoardView<bool>(BoardSize);
        var AllOrientations = new[] {
            ShipOrientation.Horizontal,
            ShipOrientation.Vertical };

        foreach (var ship in ships)
        {
            while (!ship.IsPlaced)
            {
                var l = rand.Pick(board.Select(c => c.Location));
                var o = rand.Pick(AllOrientations);
                if (ship.IsLegal(ships, BoardSize, l, o))
                    ship.Place(l, o);
            }
        }
    }

    public void NewGame(Size size, TimeSpan timeSpan)
    {
        var board = new BoardView<bool>(size);
        this.guesses = new List<Point>(
            board.Select(x => x.Location).Shuffle(rand));
        nextGuess = 0;
    }

    public System.Drawing.Point GetShot()
    {
        return guesses[nextGuess++];
    }

    // empty methods left out 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

My entry.

Nothing terribly special, and I didn't get time to add all the good ideas I had.

But it seems to play fairly well.  We'll see how it does in competition:

(put this in file `Missouri.cs` and added to project.)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Battleship
{
    // The Empire of Japan surrendered on the deck of the USS Missouri on Sept. 2, 1945
    public class USSMissouri : IBattleshipOpponent
    {
        public String  Name    { get { return name; } }
        public Version Version { get { return ver;  } }

#region IBattleship Interface
        // IBattleship::NewGame
        public void NewGame(Size gameSize, TimeSpan timeSpan)
        {
            size      = gameSize;
            shotBoard = new ShotBoard(size);
            attackVector = new Stack<Attack>();
        }

        // IBattleship::PlaceShips
        public void PlaceShips(ReadOnlyCollection<Ship> ships)
        {
            HunterBoard board;
            targetBoards = new List<HunterBoard>();
            shotBoard    = new ShotBoard(size);
            foreach (Ship s in ships)
            {
                board = new HunterBoard(this, size, s);
                targetBoards.Add(board);

                // REWRITE: to ensure valid board placement.
                s.Place(
                    new Point(
                        rand.Next(size.Width),
                        rand.Next(size.Height)),
                    (ShipOrientation)rand.Next(2));
            }
        }

        // IBattleship::GetShot
        public Point GetShot()
        {
            Point p = new Point();

            if (attackVector.Count() > 0)
            {
                p = ExtendShot();
                return p;
            }

            // Contemplate a shot at every-single point, and measure how effective it would be.
            Board potential = new Board(size);
            for(p.Y=0; p.Y<size.Height; ++p.Y)
            {
                for(p.X=0; p.X<size.Width; ++p.X)
                {
                    if (shotBoard.ShotAt(p))
                    {
                        potential[p] = 0;
                        continue;
                    }

                    foreach(HunterBoard b in targetBoards)
                    {
                        potential[p] += b.GetWeightAt(p);
                    }
                }
            }

            // Okay, we have the shot potential of the board.
            // Lets pick a weighted-random spot.
            Point shot;
            shot = potential.GetWeightedRandom(rand.NextDouble());

            shotBoard[shot] = Shot.Unresolved;

            return shot;
        }

        public Point ExtendShot()
        {
            // Lets consider North, South, East, and West of the current shot.
            // and measure the potential of each
            Attack attack = attackVector.Peek();

            Board potential = new Board(size);

            Point[] points = attack.GetNextTargets();
            foreach(Point p in points)
            {
                if (shotBoard.ShotAt(p))
                {
                    potential[p] = 0;
                    continue;
                }

                foreach(HunterBoard b in targetBoards)
                {
                    potential[p] += b.GetWeightAt(p);
                }
            }

            Point shot = potential.GetBestShot();
            shotBoard[shot] = Shot.Unresolved;
            return shot;
        }

        // IBattleship::NewMatch
        public void NewMatch(string opponent)
        {
        }
        public void OpponentShot(Point shot)
        {
        }
        public void ShotHit(Point shot, bool sunk)
        {
            shotBoard[shot] = Shot.Hit;

            if (!sunk)
            {
                if (attackVector.Count == 0) // This is a first hit, open an attackVector
                {   
                    attackVector.Push(new Attack(this, shot));
                }
                else
                {
                    attackVector.Peek().AddHit(shot);    // Add a hit to our current attack.
                }
            }

            // What if it is sunk?  Close the top attack, which we've been pursuing.
            if (sunk)
            {
                if (attackVector.Count > 0)
                {
                    attackVector.Pop();
                }
            }
        }
        public void ShotMiss(Point shot)
        {
            shotBoard[shot] = Shot.Miss;

            foreach(HunterBoard b in targetBoards)
            {
                b.ShotMiss(shot);  // Update the potential map.
            }
        }
        public void GameWon()
        {
            Trace.WriteLine  ("I won the game!");
        }
        public void GameLost()
        {
            Trace.WriteLine  ("I lost the game!");
        }
        public void MatchOver()
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("This match is over.");
        }

#endregion 

        public ShotBoard theShotBoard
        {
            get { return shotBoard; }
        }
        public Size theBoardSize
        {
            get { return size; }
        }

        private Random rand = new Random();
        private Version ver = new Version(6, 3); // USS Missouri is BB-63, hence version 6.3
        private String name = "USS Missouri (abelenky@alum.mit.edu)";
        private Size size;
        private List<HunterBoard> targetBoards;
        private ShotBoard shotBoard;
        private Stack<Attack> attackVector;
    }

    // An Attack is the data on the ship we are currently working on sinking.
    // It consists of a set of points, horizontal and vertical, from a central point.
    // And can be extended in any direction.
    public class Attack
    {
        public Attack(USSMissouri root, Point p)
        {
            Player = root;
            hit = p;
            horzExtent = new Extent(p.X, p.X);
            vertExtent = new Extent(p.Y, p.Y);
        }

        public Extent HorizontalExtent
        {
            get { return horzExtent; }
        }
        public Extent VerticalExtent
        {
            get { return vertExtent; }
        }
        public Point  FirstHit
        {
            get { return hit; }
        }

        public void AddHit(Point p)
        {
            if (hit.X == p.X) // New hit in the vertical direction
            {
                vertExtent.Min = Math.Min(vertExtent.Min, p.Y);
                vertExtent.Max = Math.Max(vertExtent.Max, p.Y);
            }
            else if (hit.Y == p.Y)
            {
                horzExtent.Min = Math.Min(horzExtent.Min, p.X);
                horzExtent.Max = Math.Max(horzExtent.Max, p.X);
            }
        }
        public Point[] GetNextTargets() 
        {
            List<Point> bors = new List<Point>();

            Point p;

            p = new Point(hit.X, vertExtent.Min-1);
            while (p.Y >= 0 && Player.theShotBoard[p] == Shot.Hit)
            {
                if (Player.theShotBoard[p] == Shot.Miss)
                {
                    break; // Don't add p to the List 'bors.  
                }
                --p.Y;
            }
            if (p.Y >= 0 && Player.theShotBoard[p] == Shot.None) // Add next-target only if there is no shot here yet.
            {
                bors.Add(p);
            }

            //-------------------

            p = new Point(hit.X, vertExtent.Max+1);
            while (p.Y < Player.theBoardSize.Height && Player.theShotBoard[p] == Shot.Hit)
            {
                if (Player.theShotBoard[p] == Shot.Miss)
                {
                    break; // Don't add p to the List 'bors.  
                }
                ++p.Y;
            }
            if (p.Y < Player.theBoardSize.Height && Player.theShotBoard[p] == Shot.None)
            {
                bors.Add(p);
            }

            //-------------------

            p = new Point(horzExtent.Min-1, hit.Y);
            while (p.X >= 0 && Player.theShotBoard[p] == Shot.Hit)
            {
                if (Player.theShotBoard[p] == Shot.Miss)
                {
                    break; // Don't add p to the List 'bors.  
                }
                --p.X;
            }
            if (p.X >= 0 && Player.theShotBoard[p] == Shot.None)
            {
                bors.Add(p);
            }

            //-------------------

            p = new Point(horzExtent.Max+1, hit.Y);
            while (p.X < Player.theBoardSize.Width && Player.theShotBoard[p] == Shot.Hit)
            {
                if (Player.theShotBoard[p] == Shot.Miss)
                {
                    break; // Don't add p to the List 'bors.  
                }
                ++p.X;
            }
            if (p.X < Player.theBoardSize.Width && Player.theShotBoard[p] == Shot.None)
            {
                bors.Add(p);
            }

            return bors.ToArray();
        }

        private Point hit; 
        private Extent horzExtent;
        private Extent vertExtent;
        private USSMissouri Player;
    }

    public struct Extent
    {
        public Extent(Int32 min, Int32 max)
        {
            Min = min;
            Max = max;
        }
        public Int32 Min;
        public Int32 Max;
    }

    public class Board  // The potential-Board, which measures the full potential of each square.
    {
        // A Board is the status of many things.
        public Board(Size boardsize)
        {
            size = boardsize;
            grid = new int[size.Width , size.Height];
            Array.Clear(grid,0,size.Width*size.Height);
        }

        public int this[int c,int r]
        {
            get { return grid[c,r];  }
            set { grid[c,r] = value; }
        }
        public int this[Point p]
        {
            get { return grid[p.X, p.Y];  }
            set { grid[p.X, p.Y] = value; }
        }

        public Point GetWeightedRandom(double r)
        {
            Int32 sum = 0;
            foreach(Int32 i in grid)
            {
                sum += i;
            }

            Int32 index = (Int32)(r*sum);

            Int32 x=0, y=0;
            for(y=0; y<size.Height; ++y)
            {
                for(x=0; x<size.Width; ++x)
                {
                    if (grid[x,y] == 0) continue; // Skip any zero-cells
                    index -= grid[x,y];
                    if (index < 0) break;
                }
                if (index < 0) break;
            }

            if (x == 10 || y == 10)
                throw new Exception("WTF");

            return new Point(x,y);
        }

        public Point GetBestShot()
        {
            int max=grid[0,0];
            for(int y=0; y<size.Height; ++y)
            {
                for (int x=0; x<size.Width; ++x)
                {
                    max = (grid[x,y] > max)? grid[x,y] : max;
                }
            }

            for(int y=0; y<size.Height; ++y)
            {
                for (int x=0; x<size.Width; ++x)
                {
                    if (grid[x,y] == max)
                    {
                        return new Point(x,y);
                    }
                }
            }
            return new Point(0,0);
        }

        public bool IsZero()
        {
            foreach(Int32 p in grid)
            {
                if (p > 0)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        public override String ToString()
        {
            String output = "";
            String horzDiv = "   +----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+\n";
            String disp;
            int x,y;

            output += "      A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H    I    J    \n" + horzDiv;

            for(y=0; y<size.Height; ++y)
            {
                output += String.Format("{0} ", y+1).PadLeft(3);
                for(x=0; x<size.Width; ++x)
                {
                    switch(grid[x,y])
                    {
                        case (int)Shot.None:       disp = "";  break;
                        case (int)Shot.Hit:        disp = "#"; break;
                        case (int)Shot.Miss:       disp = "."; break;
                        case (int)Shot.Unresolved: disp = "?"; break;
                        default:                   disp = "!"; break;
                    }

                    output += String.Format("| {0} ", disp.PadLeft(2));
                }
                output += "|\n" + horzDiv;
            }

            return output;
        }

        protected Int32[,] grid;
        protected Size     size;
    }

    public class HunterBoard
    {
        public HunterBoard(USSMissouri root, Size boardsize, Ship target)
        {
            size = boardsize;
            grid = new int[size.Width , size.Height];
            Array.Clear(grid,0,size.Width*size.Height);

            Player = root;
            Target = target;
            Initialize();
        }

        public void Initialize()
        {
            int x, y, i;

            for(y=0; y<size.Height; ++y)
            {
                for(x=0; x<size.Width - Target.Length+1; ++x)
                {
                    for(i=0; i<Target.Length; ++i)
                    {
                        grid[x+i,y]++;
                    }
                }
            }

            for(y=0; y<size.Height-Target.Length+1; ++y)
            {
                for(x=0; x<size.Width; ++x)
                {
                    for(i=0; i<Target.Length; ++i)
                    {
                        grid[x,y+i]++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public int this[int c,int r]
        {
            get { return grid[c,r];  }
            set { grid[c,r] = value; }
        }
        public int this[Point p]
        {
            get { return grid[p.X, p.Y];  }
            set { grid[p.X, p.Y] = value; }
        }

        public void ShotMiss(Point p)
        {
            int x,y;
            int min, max;

            min = Math.Max(p.X-Target.Length+1, 0);
            max = Math.Min(p.X, size.Width-Target.Length);
            for(x=min; x<=max; ++x)
            {
                DecrementRow(p.Y, x, x+Target.Length-1);
            }

            min = Math.Max(p.Y-Target.Length+1, 0);
            max = Math.Min(p.Y, size.Height-Target.Length);
            for(y=min; y<=max; ++y)
            {
                DecrementColumn(p.X, y, y+Target.Length-1);
            } 

            grid[p.X, p.Y] = 0;
        }

        public void ShotHit(Point p)
        {
        }

        public override String ToString()
        {
            String output = String.Format("Target size is {0}\n", Target.Length);
            String horzDiv = "   +----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+\n";
            int x,y;

            output += "      A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H    I    J    \n" + horzDiv;
            for(y=0; y<size.Height; ++y)
            {
                output += String.Format("{0} ", y+1).PadLeft(3);
                for(x=0; x<size.Width; ++x)
                {
                    output += String.Format("| {0} ", grid[x,y].ToString().PadLeft(2));
                }
                output += "|\n" + horzDiv;
            }
            return output;
        }

        // If we shoot at point P, how does that affect the potential of the board?
        public Int32 GetWeightAt(Point p)
        {
            int x,y;
            int potential = 0;
            int min, max;

            min = Math.Max(p.X-Target.Length+1, 0);
            max = Math.Min(p.X, size.Width-Target.Length);
            for(x=min; x<=max; ++x)
            {
                if (Player.theShotBoard.isMissInRow(p.Y, x, x+Target.Length-1) == false)
                {
                    ++potential;
                }
            }

            min = Math.Max(p.Y-Target.Length+1, 0);
            max = Math.Min(p.Y, size.Height-Target.Length);
            for(y=min; y<=max; ++y)
            {
                if (Player.theShotBoard.isMissInColumn(p.X, y, y+Target.Length-1) == false)
                {
                    ++potential;
                }
            } 

            return potential;
        }

        public void DecrementRow(int row, int rangeA, int rangeB)
        {
            int x;
            for(x=rangeA; x<=rangeB; ++x)
            {
                grid[x,row] = (grid[x,row]==0)? 0 : grid[x,row]-1;
            }
        }
        public void DecrementColumn(int col, int rangeA, int rangeB)
        {
            int y;
            for(y=rangeA; y<=rangeB; ++y)
            {
                grid[col,y] = (grid[col,y]==0)? 0 : grid[col,y]-1;
            }
        }

        private Ship Target = null;
        private USSMissouri Player;
        private Int32[,] grid;
        private Size     size;
    }

    public enum Shot
    {
        None = 0,
        Hit = 1,
        Miss = 2,
        Unresolved = 3
    };

    public class ShotBoard
    {
        public ShotBoard(Size boardsize)
        {
            size = boardsize;
            grid = new Shot[size.Width , size.Height];

            for(int y=0; y<size.Height; ++y)
            {
                for(int x=0; x<size.Width; ++x)
                {
                    grid[x,y] = Shot.None;
                }
            }
        }

        public Shot this[int c,int r]
        {
            get { return grid[c,r];  }
            set { grid[c,r] = value; }
        }
        public Shot this[Point p]
        {
            get { return grid[p.X, p.Y];  }
            set { grid[p.X, p.Y] = value; }
        }

        public override String ToString()
        {
            String output = "";
            String horzDiv = "   +----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+\n";
            String disp;
            int x,y;

            output += "      A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H    I    J    \n" + horzDiv;

            for(y=0; y<size.Height; ++y)
            {
                output += String.Format("{0} ", y+1).PadLeft(3);
                for(x=0; x<size.Width; ++x)
                {
                    switch(grid[x,y])
                    {
                        case Shot.None:       disp = "";  break;
                        case Shot.Hit:        disp = "#"; break;
                        case Shot.Miss:       disp = "."; break;
                        case Shot.Unresolved: disp = "?"; break;
                        default:              disp = "!"; break;
                    }

                    output += String.Format("| {0} ", disp.PadLeft(2));
                }
                output += "|\n" + horzDiv;
            }
            return output;
        }

        // Functions to find shots on the board, at a specific point, or in a row or column, within a range
        public bool ShotAt(Point p)
        {
            return !(this[p]==Shot.None);
        }
        public bool isMissInColumn(int col, int rangeA, int rangeB)
        {
            for(int y=rangeA; y<=rangeB; ++y)
            {
                if (grid[col,y] == Shot.Miss)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        public bool isMissInRow(int row, int rangeA, int rangeB)
        {
            for(int x=rangeA; x<=rangeB; ++x)
            {
                if (grid[x,row] == Shot.Miss)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        protected Shot[,] grid;
        protected Size     size;
    }
}
```

Comment: And now that I've submitted my entry, some rough stats: vs. BP7 44% wins.   /   vs. Dreadnought 20% wins.   /  vs. Farnsworth 42% wins.  It was a fun project.

Answer (score 2):

This is not minimax. Actually after placing the ships, can't each player play on its own, resulting in a number of turns it took him to sink every opponent ship? The one that took less turns wins.

I don't think that there are any good general strategies beyond sinking hit ships and trying to minimize the number of shots to cover the remaining possible places where ships might hide.

Of course there might be counter-strategies for anything that's not random. But I don't think that there are strategies that are good against all possible players.

Comment: Potentially, yes, they could play on their own. That is not how this will be run. Great idea, though.  In this competition, I want it to be possible to statistically avoid your opponent's shots.

Comment: I see. Using data from prior games against the same opponent one might be able to adapt to him?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I think the biggest problem with the puzzle is that its essentially two moves.  One move is placing your ships, the other is finding the enemy ships (however segmented that second part might be, aside from trying to beat a clock with a random factor, its just 'run your algorithm').  There's no mechanism to try to determine and then counter an enemy strategy, which is what makes similar competitions based around successive rounds of "rock paper scissors" pretty interesting.

Also, I think it would be cooler if you specified the game as a network protocol and then provided the framework to implement that protocol in C#, rather than dictate that all solutions should be C#, but that's just my opinion.

EDIT: I rescind my initial point, since I didn't read the competition rules carefully enough.

Comment: Not all solutions must be in C#.  I can compile and link-in a separate assembly.  Also, you should be able to statistically counter your opponent.

Comment: J#? maybe? Lol, jk.  I do have a TCP framework for this, but this tournament needs to run very quickly.

Comment: Why would you assume that TCP communication between two processes on the same machine wouldn't be blazingly fast?

Comment: @Jherico:  If I was using TCP, I would be isolating the engines on their own PCs so that they could use any CPU resources they wanted.

Comment: Even so, two machines on the same lan could easily complete a game in under a second with the network overhead being minimal

Answer (score 2):

I always liked starting in the middle and spiraling away from that one point leaving no more than 1 blank space between any other points to account for that goddam sub... the space between shots was dependent on which ships were sunk.  if the B-ship was last, the shots only had to leave 4 spaces in between to minimize wasted shots

Comment: So...  I just need to stay away from the middle?  :)

Comment: You also need to stay away from the edges, because an edge hit contains more information for your opponent than a non-edge hit.  So you should place all your ships in a non-middle, non-edge region.  Unless that's what they're *expecting* you to do.

Comment: If you start by leaving 3 or 4 spaces, you might be lucky enough to hit the sub anyway. If not, go back and try filling in the gaps.

More at: http://www.somethinkodd.com/oddthinking/2009/10/29/battleship-strategy/

Comment: The ship with two holes is not a goddamn *sub*, it's a goddamn *PT boat*.  The sub has three holes. :)

Answer (score 2):

There was a similar competition run by Dr James Heather of The University of Surrey on behalf of the British Computer Society.

Limitations were placed on resources - namely maximum processor time per turn, no state could be stored between moves, maximum heap size imposed. To limit time the AI could submit a move at any point within the time slot and would be asked for a move upon termination of the turn.

Very interesting - see more at: http://www.bcsstudentcontest.com/

Might give you some more ideas.

Answer (score 2):

As it is, the solution opens and runs with no modification in monodevelop in ubuntu 9.10 linux

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

- Anything that is deemed against the spirit of the competition will be grounds for disqualification.
- Interfering with an opponent is against the spirit of the competition.

please define "against the spirit of the competition" and "interfering with an opponent"?

Also - to simplify, I recommend that you:

- disallow using CPU at all during opponent's CPU slot.
- disallow thread parallelism and instead give more CPU seconds on a single thread. This will simplify programming of AI and won't hurt anyone who is CPU/memory-bound anyway.

PS - a question for the CS post-docs lurking here: isn't this game solvable (i.e. is there a single, best strategy?). yes, the board size and number of steps makes minimax et al mandatory, but still I have to wonder... it's far from Go and chess in complexity.

Comment: I had reflection in mind when I said "Interfering".  I don't want competitors to win because they bit-twiddled another engine to death.

Comment: I'd suggest that espionage is an important part of modern warfare, so reflecting to find the targets would be ideal -- after all, it was one of the methods used during the second world war...

Comment: I have a framework for isolating the engines onto different PCs, communicating over TCP/IP, rendering Reflection worthless.  However, due to my estimated number of entries, This would make the competition take a prohibitively long time.

Comment: I didn't know they had Reflection back then!

Answer (score 1):

I predict that the person who manages to reverse engineer their opponents random seed and call pattern will win.

Not sure how likely that is though.

Comment: The opponents have the option of using a CSPRNG.

Comment: Good point, although I admit that reverse engineering such a seed is beyond my expertise anyway.

I guess that most vulnerable aspect would be the fire pattern selection algorithm- but even then you wouldn't necessarily gain much from breaking it, as there is no way you could move your ships once the game has started.

Comment: When I was applying for research internship, we wrote battleship programs and competed.  By setting random seed was exactly how I won X)

Comment: Assuming a reasonably-simple ship placement algorithm, I would imagine one could, after getting a couple of hits on different ships, start using most of one's turn looping through all possible random seeds (probably starting with somewhere near the current time and moving forwards/backwards one step or so) and seeing which ones generate ship placements compatible with observed hits.

Answer (score 1):

It would also, presumably, be possible to run a series of these with variations on the game.

Adding in things like a 3d plane or being able to move a single ship instead of shoot for a turn would probably change the game a fair bit.

Comment: There is the "salvo" variation.  Where you get to shoot as many shots per turn as you have ships remaining.

Comment: An interesting variation as well. I seem to recall playing a computer version that had a plane as well. It would randomly fire at locations on the opposing board.

Comment: another variation: be the size of the board + number of ships.

Answer (score 1):

The one second **total** game time is machine specific.  Once second worth of CPU operations will be different on my machine compared to the tournament machine.  If I optimize the Battle Ship algorithm to utilize the most CPU time within 1 second, then it is run on a possible slower tournament machine, it will always lose.

I am not sure how to get around this limitation of the framework, but it should be addressed.

...

One idea is to do what was done in this competition http://www.bcsstudentcontest.com/

And have a maximum time per turn as opposed to maximum total game time.  This way I could limit the algorithms to fit within a know turn time.  A game might last 50 to 600+ turns, if the my algorithm manages its total game time, it might not give the enough time to do its best job or it could give too much time and lose.  It is very hard to manage the total game time within the Battleship algorithm.

I would suggest changing the rules to limit the turn time not the total game time.

**Edit**

If I wrote an algorithm that enumerates all possible shots and then ranks them, then takes the highest ranking shot.  It would take too long to generate all possible shots, so I would let the algorithm run for a certain amount of time then stop it.

If there was a turn based limit, I could let the algorithm run for 0.9 seconds and return the highest ranking shot, and be well withing the turn time limit.

If I am limited to total game time of one second, it will be difficult to determine how long the algorithm should run for each turn.  I will want to maximum my CPU time.  If a game lasted 500 round I could limit each turn to 0.002 seconds, but if a game lasted 100 rounds I could give each turn 0.01 seconds of CPU time.

It would be impractical for a algorithm to use an semi-exhaustive search of the shot space to find the best shot with the current limitation.

The 1 second total game time is limiting the type of algorithms that can be effectively used to compete in the game.

Comment: This will be run on an Intel Q9550SX quad core, 8 GB ram, Vista 64 machine.  Is 1 second going to be a limiting factor?

Comment: I guess you should make your battleship AI multithreaded, then, to calculate the max # of shots per that time interval.

Comment: the trick is how to limit the turn time interval.  If I limit it 0.00005 seconds I am safe from running over the time limit, but I am significantly limiting the search space.  If I increase the turn time limit, the search space is increased but I run the risk of running out of time.

Comment: @TonyAbell: If it's important to have a turn based time limit, why not start with an initial value and then adjust it from round to round? After about half the rounds you will most likely have found the optimal turn length for the opponent you're facing.

Comment: You should keep track of your time left, and limit it to 1/2 of the available time left.

Answer (score 1):

I'm copping out here by not putting actual code in - but I will hazard some general observations:

- Since all ships are at least 2 cells in size, you can use an optimization I saw on an implementation of the game in Space Quest V - which only fires at alternate cells in a diamond pattern while it is "seeking" a target. This eliminates half the squares, while still guaranteeing that you will find all the ships eventually.
- A random firing pattern when seeking targets will statistically yield the best results over many games.

Answer (score 1):

![Probability Density][1]enter image description her

![enter image description here][2]

I experimented with comparing the results of randon shooting vs a dumb hunt/target and finally a sophisticated search.

The best solution appears to be to create a probability density function for the how likely any individual square is used by the remaining ships, and aim with the square with the highest value.

You can see my results here [enter link description here](http://www.datagenetics.com/blog/december32011/index.html)

Comment: Could you perhaps fix your answer and especially your images and link?

Answer (score -2):

"Battleship" is what's known as a classic computer science NP-complete problem.

**http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_NP-complete_problems**

(look for Battleship - it's there, under games and puzzles)

Comment: Which is a battleship puzzle (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battleship_(puzzle)), not Battleship the game (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battleship_(game)).

Comment: Yeah, as Jason stated this is an entirely different animal.

Comment: Hehehe. Next assignment I get at work I'm going to say it's NP-complete, then take a long lunch. :-)