# Where has this cluster search algorithm been presented before?

Tags: algorithm, search, complexity-theory, discrete-mathematics, mathematical-optimization

See: http://kks.cabal.fi/GoodEnoughSearch

I have gone through quite many papers and sites. I have not found where this algorithm has been presented before, or that someone has made something similar, but better or more general. The algorithm is pretty simple and thus should be found quite easily by anyone facing the same kind of problems I have faced.

Answer (score 1):

It reminds me of the Monte Carlo method.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method

Comment: It reminds me about that battleship example for which I made this when I was 17 :) .. but no this is not Monte Carlo, I think. I have to look those see also things, because there might be something

Comment: "First a player makes some random shots."  well, if you would use a 2 dimensional modification for restricted clusters (no looping from side to side) of that algorithm, you would be selecting greedily the places first which eliminate the most places where a ship might be - not in random. I don't remember, that did that work for the ship distribution (cluster length distribution) of the battleship game, but that's from where the idea came.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631414/what-is-the-best-battleship-ai/1662235#1662235

Hehe. Should have searched more about battleship algorithms. 
Someone else has done it too for battleships, but the question still remains.