# Generate and repeat number in C#

Tags: c#, repeat, enumerable

I want to generate an array that has 144 number from 1->36 in random order (so each number is repeated 4 times). Can we use Enumerable.Repeat and Enumerable.Range to do that. If yes than please explain to me how?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, creating the sequence with all the numbers in is easy:

```
var items = from x in Enumerable.Range(1, 36)
            from y in Enumerable.Repeat(x, 4)
            select y;
```

Then you can just use `ToArray` to get it into an array and shuffle it. There are numerous questions about shuffling an array in C# on SO, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287567). You could either use that code directly, or call `ToArray` and shuffle the array in place without yielding it at the end.

Comment: and more elegant that my multiple Concat ;)

Comment: thanks for the comment, but now I need to fill the generated array to an [9,16] array, can you suggest a good way for me?

Comment: @A New Chicken: I suspect that using Buffer.BlockCopy will work for you... it's worth trying, anyway. (i.e. create the 2D array and use Buffer.BlockCopy to copy the 1D array into it.)

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] numbers = Enumerable.Range(0, 144).Select(i => (i % 36)+1).OrderBy(g => Guid.NewGuid()).ToArray();
```

Comment: Probably not important in this case, but this way of shuffling ends up being O(n log n) where it only needs to be O(n).

Answer (score 0):

```
// Generate the list (not in random order)
var one_to_36 = Enumerable.Range(1, 36);
var lst = one_to_36.Concat(one_to_36).Concat(one_to_36).Concat(one_to_36).ToList();

// Randomize the list by swapping random elements
Random rnd = new Random();
for(int i = 0; i < lst.Count; i++)
{
    int i1 = rnd.Next(lst.Count);
    int i2 = rnd.Next(lst.Count);
    int tmp = lst[i1];
    lst[i1] = lst[i2];
    lst[i2] = tmp;
}
```

Comment: Swapping random elements in this way doesn't give a good random distribution - there's a better way of shuffling a collection, as linked to in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var seq = Enumerable.Range(0, 144);    
var all = seq.ToList();
var random = new Random();
var result = seq.Select(i => {
 var index = random.Next()%all.Count;
 var r = all[index] % 36 + 1; all.RemoveAt(index);
 return r;
}).ToList();
```