# Generating 2 Random Numbers that are Different C#

Tags: c#

I would like to generate two random numbers that are different from each other. For example, if the first random number generates 5, I want the next random number generated to not equal 5. This is my code thus far:

```
Random ran = new Random();
int getRanNum1 = ran.Next(10);
int getRanNum2 = ran.Next(10);
```

How do I tell getRandNum2 to not equal the value generated in getRandNum1?

Comment: You do realize that that makes `getRanNum2` a little less random? Especially on a small range like `0..9`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With a loop:

```
int getRanNum2 = ran.Next(10);
while(getRanNum2 == getRanNum1)
    getRanNum2 = ran.Next(10);
```

Answer (score 9):

While the loop-and-check approach is likely suitable here, a variant of this question is "How to get N distinct random numbers in a range (or set)?"

For that, one possible alternative (and one that I like, which is why I wrote this answer) is to build said range (or set), [*shuffle* the items](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle), and then take the first N items.

An implementation of the Fischer-Yates shuffle can be found [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2301091/2864740). Slightly cleaned up for the situation:

```
void Shuffle (int arr[]) {
  Random rnd = new Random();
  for (int i = arr.Length; i > 1; i--) {
    int pos = rnd.Next(i);
    var x = arr[i - 1];
    arr[i - 1] = arr[pos];
    arr[pos] = x;
  }
}

// usage
var numbers = Enumerable.Range(0,10).ToArray();
Shuffle(numbers);
int getRanNum1 = numbers[0];
int getRanNum2 = numbers[1];
```

Since we know that *only* N (2) elements are being selected, the `Shuffle` method above can actually be modified such that only N (2) swaps are done. This is because `arr[i - 1]`, for each `i`, is only swapped once (although it can be swapped with itself). In any case, this left as an exercise for the reader.