# C# random records from list with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a more efficent way to randomise a set of LINQ results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633397/is-there-a-more-efficent-way-to-randomise-a-set-of-linq-results)

I have a list having 300 records.  I want to return only distinct, random records and only 50 records with LINQ:

```
myCollection = list.Distinct().Take(50).ToList(); // myCollection is the new list
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can order the list by random before `Take(50)`.
Should be like this:

```
myCollection = list.Distinct().OrderBy(s => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(50).ToList();
```

Idea of `Guid.NewGuid()` is not so efficient i think but you can consider using `Random` generator.

Comment: sorry, place wrong code, already fixed.