# Dictionary<char, char> to map an alphabet -- with unique keys & values

Tags: c#, collections, random, dictionary

I need to create a Dictionary that expresses a mapping between each char in an alphabet and another char in that alphabet, where both the key and value are unique -- like a very simple cipher that expresses how to code/decode a message. There can be no duplicate keys or values.

Does anyone see what is wrong with this code? It is still producing duplicate **values** in the mapping despite the fact that on each iteration the pool of available characters decreases for each value already used.

```
        string source_alphabet = _alphabet; //ie "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
        string target_alphabet = _alphabet;

        Dictionary<char, char> _map = new Dictionary<char, char>();

        for (int i = 0; i < source_alphabet.Length; i++)
        {
            int random = _random.Next(target_alphabet.Length - 1); //select a random index

            char _output = target_alphabet[random]  //get the char at the random index

            _map.Add(source_alphabet[i], _output); //add to the dictionary

            target_alphabet = target_alphabet.Replace(_output.ToString(), string.Empty); 
            // remove the char we just added from the remaining alphabet
        }
```

Thanks.

Comment: this type of code does not guarantee that `random` is always different from `i` - thus duplicates can (and usually will) happen...

Comment: That shouldn't matter because random doesn't need to be different from i. A character that has already been added as a value to the dictionary shouldn't even be in the available pool of chars to choose from. If by chance A ends up mapping to A that's fine. Its just that there can't be any duplicate values in the dictionary.

Comment: Delete the char from the target_alphabet every time after random index has been generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider performing a simple [Fisher Yates shuffle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287567/c-is-using-random-and-orderby-a-good-shuffle-algorithm/1287572#1287572) over one or both sequences of the alphabet, then you can simply iterate over the output and put together your mapper.

Pseudocode

```
Shuffle(sequence1)
Shuffle(sequence2)

for index 0 to 25
    dictionary add sequence1[index], sequence2[index]
```

When you try to select a random value *each time*, then there is a high probability that you will get a collision and therefore have a non-unique value selected. The answer is usually to shuffle, then select in order.

Answer (score 1):

"a quick fix" though not optimal would be (if mapping A to A is NOT allowed)

```
 int random = _random.Next(target_alphabet.Length - 1);
 while ( source_alphabet[i] == target_alphabet[random] ) {random = _random.Next(target_alphabet.Length - 1);};
```

if mapping A to A is allowed then ignore the above change... BUT at least change the last line to

```
target_alphabet = target_alphabet.Remove ( random, 1 );
```

Comment: Not sure why but I still get duplicates, whether I use .Replace() or .Remove() or the Array.FindAll() method that mishau posted. I think there maybe something else going on b/c this should work.

Comment: Then there must be something in the code not shown... is this multi-threaded ? any static variables ? any "duplicate" variable names which could cause some issues ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could add another "for" loop on the target_alphabet inside the existing "for" loop and check for the characters not be same with a small "if" condition and continue the inner loop if same or break if not.

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < source_alphabet.Length; i++)
    {
        int random = _random.Next(target_alphabet.Length - 1); //select a random index

        char _output = target_alphabet[random];  //get the char at the random index


        _map.Add(source_alphabet[i], _output); //add to the dictionary

        // remove the char we just added from the remaining alphabet
        target_alphabet = target_alphabet.Remove(random, 1);


    }
```