# Shuffle DataTable Rows by specific column C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, datatable

I'm trying to shuffle DataTable rows by a specific column (campaign_id) in this example.
I tried what's suggested in this question 
[cannot shuffle rows of DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37764468/cannot-shuffle-rows-of-datatable)

but I need to be more specific as I mentioned,

Here is an example:
this is the DataTable I have, it is sorted by campaign_id column

[image: soruce]

and I want the result to be (shuffling campaign_id) like this:

[image: result]

Comment: "at least not consecutive" but in your result there are consecutive

Comment: @Rango the example shows what i'm looking for exactly.

Comment: Well, if you cant show what you have tried, could you at least explain the rules for this sorting? It's not obvious

Comment: If you're truly shuffling the data, "which column" it's shuffled by shouldn't matter at all.

Comment: shuffling != alternating. So [edit] the question, what exactly do you want.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov i did, sorry for that.

Comment: @B.Simboliq a better word for what you're trying to do would be "alternating" rather than "shuffling"

Answer (score 1):

```
var rnd = new Random();
var shuffled = dataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().OrderBy(r => rnd.Next()).CopyToDataTable();
```