# Need a better design for a "callback dispatcher" component

Tags: c#, algorithm

From a client application I am sending a request/transaction (containing an operation to perform (and parameters) + transactionID) to a remote queue. The remote server dequeue the request at some point and takes some time to process it.

Once it is done processing it, it sends a reponse on the client queue (containing the applicative response + the transactionID) ... so this is a totally "disconnected" communication mode, the only way that the client can map the response to the request is via the transactionID.

Message response is dequeued on client side, and matched with the original request (based on the transactionID).

What I am doing right now is that when the client post the request to the server queue, it adds a callback to a dictionnary keeping transactionId and callback (delegate). This is a `Dictionary<int, object>` mapping a transactionId back to a callback to call with the result of the operation.

The callbacks/delegates are stored as object due to the fact that depending of the request, the callback delegate signature is different (for example a response may return a `List<string>` whereas another response may return an `int`).

When the client queue dequeues a response, it knows the type of the response (and therefore the corresponding signature of the callback), therefore it gets the callback from the dictionary, based on the transactionID. It then casts the object back to the corresponding delegate type and invoke the callback.

I find this approach not very "sexy" but I do not really see another way of performing such a task.

Is there any better way of performing this ?

If the problem is not clear enough, please let me know and will clarify with some edits.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#: Is using Random and OrderBy a good shuffle algorithm?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287567/c-is-using-random-and-orderby-a-good-shuffle-algorithm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might find Reactive Extensions a handy tool for that kind of messaging.

First, make all your responses implement some interface or base class, like IMessage. Each kind of response should be encapsulated in a separate class like here

```
public interface IMessage
{
    int TransactionId { get; }
}

public class UserListMessage : IMessage
{
    int TransactionId { get; set; }
    public List<string> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Then make your message queue implement `IObservable<IMessage>`. Reactive extensions provides a ready to use implementation called `Subject<T>`, you might want to wrap it or something.

Observable implements a `Subscribe(IObserver<IMessage> observer)` method which stores observers somewhere in an internal list. When a new response arrives an `OnNext(IMessage message)` method is called on each subscribed observer.

Finally, your response handling registration code might look like:

```
var subscription = myQueue
    .OfType<UserListMessage>()
    .Where(msg => msg.TransactionId == id)
    .Subscribe(callback);
```

That will register callback for a message of type UserListMessage with given transaction ID.
Probably you will also want to unsubscribe somewhere. That will be:

```
subscription.Dispose();
```

That was a brief sample how that would look like with Rx. Now go and find some more detailed tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an enumeration, on the client side, that define all the type of possible responses you can get. Then you can code a function that contain a big "select case" that associate each value of the enumeration to it's specific function call. 
Then you can you you dictionary to associate the transactionID to the value of the enumeration that identify the kind of response you'll get from the server.

Depending on the kind of functionality you need to implement on each type of response, maybe you can find a more "object-oriented" way of doing things...
Maybe you can create a base class ResponseAction, with a common Respond method, and then you can inherits from this class for each of the possible responses type you can get, and then when you call the server, you instantiate the right Response_Specific_Action class, and put this instance in the dictionary... and then on each response you'll use your dictionary to find the right instance, and call the same standard Respond method, and it will use it's Response_Specific_Action "specific" implementation.

If you go for the ResponseAction class route, you may also consider including the transactionID as a property of the base class.

Answer (score 1):

You situation is somehow not very clear for me. first of all u did not mention which communication mechanism are u using during client server transaction? are u using WCF and its' callback channels?

why do not u wrap all your request response messages under base class which has some common data for all transactions?

u sad you are using List for your dictionary because, response differ from transaction to transaction, but again why object? is not it hard better to have common contract for all response messages? please tell us a little bit more about communication flow between your client and server

Answer (score 1):

This sounds exactly like an Adapter pattern problem.  See [this link](http://www.netobjectivestest.com/PatternRepository/index.php?title=TheAdapterPattern) for a good overview of the adapter.

What you need to do is create an abstraction that will encapsulate the whole client response (including whatever it is you do with that `List<string>` or `int`).  Your abstraction needs to be wide enough in scope so that your varying behaviors can all be covered by the same signature.  Something like this:

```
public abstract class MessageCompleteHandler
{
    public abstract void Execute();
}

//name this one better, just an example :)
public class ListOfStringHandler : MessageCompleteHandler
{
    public override void Execute()
    {
        //get list of strings
        // do something with it
    }
}

public class MessageCompleteHandlerFactory
{
    public MessageCompleteHandler GetHandler(int transactionId)
    {
        //this replaces/uses your dictionary to match handlers with types.
    }
}
```

Then, when you get the response, you use the transaction id to create the appropriate handler object, and run it.  This works best if your number of handler variants is fairly small, of course.

Comment: Nice, but where's the adapter here?

Comment: The MessageCompleteHandler implementations are adapters over the various delegates; adapting the various signatures to a single interface.

Comment: There is no delegates in your sample. I think wouldn't know how to implement your solution if i wanted. Currently it looks rather like a Command pattern, not Adapter.