# Making a shuffle method

Tags: c#, memory, shuffle

i'm currently making a c# version of memory (the game), and I'm now at the point where I need to make a method that is shuffling my cards. I have something like this (but it isn't working yet):

```
    public void shuffle()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            Random k = new Random();
            Random k2 = new Random();

            kaarten[k.Next(0, 11)] = kaarten[k2.Next(0,11)];
            kaarten[k2.Next(0, 11)] = kaarten[k.Next(0, 11)];
        }
    }
```

So i wondered if somebody could help me, thanks in advance! Steven.

Comment: Perhaps you could look into this [shuffle algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)?

Comment: Also have a look at this interesting [blog post by Jeff Atwood](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/the-danger-of-naivete.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first big problem with your code is that you're creating two instances of `Random`. The crappy seeding of `new Random()` means that those instances will most likely return exactly the same sequence.

`new Random()` seeds using `Environment.TickCount`, which only changes every few milliseconds. So if you create two instances of `Random` in quick succession, the time will be the same and thus they output the same sequence.

The proper solution is to create only one instance of `Random` at the beginning, and use if for all your randomness needs. Just be careful about multi-threading, instances of `Random` are not thread-safe.

Also note that the upper bound of `random.Next` is exclusive, so your code will work only on arrays with 11 elements. It's better to use the collection size instead of hardcoding the value.

Another problem with your code is that you didn't implement a proper swap. To swap you need to your swap has two issues: You're using new indices for the second direction, and you don't create a temporary copy in a local variable to avoid reading the overwritten value, instead of original one.

With these issues fixed your code looks like this:

```
Random random = new Random();//one persistent instance

public void shuffle()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        var i1=random.Next(kaarten.Count);
        var i2=random.Next(kaarten.Count);

        var temp=kaarten[i1];
        karten[i1]=kaarten[i2];
        karten[i2]=temp;
    }
}
```

That said, your approach is a bit inefficient, since you iterate 100000 times. The standard shuffling algorithm is a Fisher-Yates shuffle which Jon-Skeet describes at [Is using Random and OrderBy a good shuffle algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1287572/445517).

Comment: Saw and removed comment and -1.

Answer (score 3):

Considering `kaarten` is a `List` of something that represents a card...

```
public void Shuffle()
{
    // Insert cards at random order into the shuffled list
    var shuffled = new List<Card>();
    var rand = new Random();

    // As long as there are any cards left to insert randomly
    while (kaarten.Count != 0)
    {
        // Get the index of the random card to insert
        var i = rand.Next(kaarten.Count);

        // Insert it
        shuffled.Add(kaarten[i]);

        // Remove from non-shuffled list
        kaarten.RemoveAt(i);
    }

    // Set the list of cards to the shuffled list
    kaarten = shuffled;
}
```

The problems with your current code:

You don't save the randoms into local variables, and so when you attempt to swap them, you really have 4 randoms, and not 2 randoms.

Also, for swapping two elements in an array you should use a tmp variable, as seen in a Swap algorithm almost any place you'd look.

For a complete shuffle, however, my approach loses the need of deciding how many times you loop over the swap for a sufficient shuffling, and is therefore more efficient as well more understandable.

There is another way to shuffle a list, which is a bit confusing (and least efficient) but shorter, if you prefer:

```
var rand = new Random();
kaarten = kaarten.Select(x => new{X=x,R=rand.Next()})
                 .OrderBy(x => x.R)
                 .Select(x => x.X)
                 .ToList();
                 //.ToArray(); if kaarten is an array and not a list
```

Comment: OrderBy(Random.Next) isn't a good idea.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance I agree, but it might suit the needs of a simple card game.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance While it's ugly to have side effects in LINQ statements it doesn't cause any practical issues.

Answer (score 1):

First, there's this handy extension method you can use, called Swap:

```
public static void Swap<T>(this IList<T> source, int one, int two)
{
    T temp = source[one];
    source[one] = source[two];
    source[two] = temp;
}
```

Now, your code should be easy:

```
public void Shuffle()
{
    int count = kaarten.Count;
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        kaarten.Swap(rnd.Next(0, count), rnd.Next(0, count));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why check for an exception, if one would be thrown anyways in the actual swap process, if needed?

Comment: @YoryeNathan No reason, I just copy + pasted this code.

Comment: You leave the last card in an unchanged position by using `Count-1` instead of `Count`. The upper bound of `Random.Next` is exclusive.

Answer (score 1):

it shuffles the arraylist elements

```
public void Shuffle(System.Collections.ArrayList elements)
    {
        int temp;
        Random randomNumber=new Random();
        for (int n = elements.Count; n > 1; )
        {
            int k = randomNumber.Next(n); //returning random number less than the value of 'n'
            --n; //decrease radom number generation area by 1 
            //swap the last and selected values
            temp = Convert.ToInt16(elements[n]);
            elements[n] = elements[k];
            elemetns[k] = temp;
        }
    }
```

Comment: ARRAYLIST? Are you joking?

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance You also copy-pasted. He just did it with an outdated article.

Comment: but logic will be the same, try it with something else.

Comment: @harhar You could at the very least invest yourself in changing your answer to be more fit (not letting OP do it for you).

Comment: @YoryeNathan Actually, I just copied the swap method, which was then completely edited due to being more hassle than just retyping it. The shuffle method was half C&P'd off the OP (pretty much just the definition), half fixed. Cool off.

Answer (score 1):

Fisher–Yates shuffle

step 1. pull one card on random from the deck

step 2. place it in the new deck

step 3. if deck is not empty re-iterate 1 and 2

Add this to your class

```
public List<Card> Shuffle(List<Card> deck){
    List<Card> Shuffeled = new List<Card>();
    int deckSize = deck.Count;
    int selection = 0;
    Random rand = new Random();
    for(int i = 0; i < deckSize; i++){
        selection = rand.next(deck.Count-1);
        Shuffeled.Add(deck[selection]);
        deck.RemoveAt(selection);
    }
    return Shuffeled;
}
```

From your game call `kaarten = Shuffle(kaarten);`