# How to Select Random Rows in a data table of C#?

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0, datatable, dataview

My query is like this:

`select top 50 Empid  from (Select top 50 Empid from Emp inner join campus on Emp.CampusId=campus.CampusId join
  departments on Emp.department=departments.deptid
  where campus.Cname='Mumbai' ) x order by NEWID();`

But Here the number 50 is not constant it is variable(calculted value). So, I want get all the Empids in one datatable and then I need to select few of them randomly (In the above example 50)..Is it possible to do using dataview??

Comment: do you wish to do in C# or SQL server ??

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered before.

[Is using Random and OrderBy a good shuffle algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287567/is-using-random-and-orderby-a-good-shuffle-algorithm)

Please see Fisher-Yates shuffle implemented by Jon Skeet.

Basically, randomly shuffle the row numbers or ids, choose little n out of population N.

Answer (score 0):

In T-SQL, You can use `SELECT TOP (@variable)` instead of `SELECT TOP 50` as below:

```
Declare @RecCount int 

--//Set the variable @RecCount here

--//Use it to bring the top record as follows
Select top (@RecCount) Empid 
From Emp inner join campus on Emp.CampusId=campus.CampusId 
               join departments on Emp.department=departments.deptid 
Where campus.Cname='Mumbai'
Order by NEWID();
```

Comment: For example if this query returns 400 records, but I need to select only top 200 rows of which top 50 should be shuffled..