# Randomize but exclude the random variable

Tags: c#, linq

I have some code to randomize an extracted list of results but I'd prefer to not include the random variable as part of the extracted result, any ideas? Here's my code:

```
var rnd = new Random();

var numList = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
var extracted = (from n1 in numList
                 from n2 in numList
                 from n3 in numList
                 from n4 in numList
                     where n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 > 20
                 select new { n1, n2, n3, n4, Rnd = rnd.NextDouble() })
                 .OrderBy(z => z.Rnd).ToList();
```

Comment: Really what you should do is use an [actual shuffling algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) instead of sorting on a random value, which is both less efficient and more error prone.

Comment: The Random class works fine for what I'm doing, thanks anyway for the suggestion.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that you not use the `Random` class.  I'm suggesting that you use it in a way that actually produces a well defined shuffle, because your current option does not reliably produce uniformly shuffled data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to randomize output, just order by random values, without including them in selected data:

```
var rnd = new Random();
var numList = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

var extracted =  from n1 in numList
                 from n2 in numList
                 from n3 in numList
                 from n4 in numList
                 where n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 > 20
                 orderby rnd.NextDouble()
                 select new { n1, n2, n3, n4 }; // you can use ToList()
```

Comment: Thanks, looks so obvious now that I see it, feel silly now asking the question.

Comment: @user3165925 btw you can use `rnd.Next()` - it will give you random values, just as `NextDouble()` but without converting integer to double

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Although it has a dramatically higher probability of resulting in collisions, further increasing the bias introduced by the fact that sorting on a random number is not in fact shuffling data.

Comment: @Servy this is a simplest approach, which should be used if performance is not an issue, and you don't need perfect randomization. Implementation time - 5 seconds, very easy to understand

Comment: It seems fine for me to use normal random class, here's an output of calling the same function 7 times

Comment: 86, 32, 64, 83, 99, 33, 72, 62, 67,  = 598
77, 36, 84, 69, 67, 85, 49, 90, 44,  = 601
97, 37, 95, 37, 71, 61, 66, 93, 41,  = 598
67, 67, 79, 33, 87, 68, 132, 29, 35,  = 597
122, 45, 31, 67, 31, 87, 81, 54, 80,  = 598
124, 28, 46, 132, 68, 39, 27, 67, 67,  = 598
39, 95, 95, 39, 44, 83, 74, 44, 88,  = 601
65, 68, 83, 70, 31, 81, 70, 64, 67,  = 599

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy As opposed to spending 10 seconds copying a *real* shuffling algorithm into your code, having reliable, efficient, effective, readable, and maintainable shuffling.  Added cost, 5 seconds.

Comment: @chillydk147 The question is not whether or not you use the `Random` class (unless you're in a context in which you really do need cryptographic strength randomness) but *how* you use it.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I'm not even saying it's the primary reason.  It's simply a nice added benefit to get a fairly dramatic efficiency boost while also fixing all of the other important issues such as what probably *is* the most important issue, removing a bias in the shuffling algorithm.

Comment: @Servy Are there any examples of this "Fisher–Yates shuffle" packaged within a C# Method which I can quickly add to my program?

Comment: @chillydk147 Yes, there are.  A simple Google (or SO) search can help you find one in seconds.

Comment: @chillydk147 here is sample http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287567/is-using-random-and-orderby-a-good-shuffle-algorithm?lq=1