# Migrate C# code from Console to Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, user-interface, buttonclick

I have been learning C# using the book "Programming in the Key of C#...", this book has been very good in helping me understand the language but only deals with Console programs. I am ready to move on to developing versions of my past coding projects as Windows form applications but one program in particular is causing me a lot of frustration. I developed a simple movie trivia program utilizing arrays to hold the questions, answer choices, and the correct answer. It worked by displaying on the console the questions, the possible answers and waited for the user to provide a response (basically A,B,C or D) by using Console.Readline() to assign the response.

Now I want to be able to have the user enter the answer by selecting 1 of 4 buttons (A through D). Based on my old code, I am unsure how I get the program to wait for the user to click one of the buttons. I assume i need to change the nature of the loops but I just cant figure out how. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is a snippet of my  Console code:

```
while (iAsked < 5)
    {   
        iLocation = rand.Next(0, astrQuestions.GetLength(0));

        if (list.Contains(iLocation))
            rand.Next(0, astrQuestions.GetLength(0));
        else
        {
            iAsked++;
            list.Add(iLocation);
            Console.WriteLine("Question {0}", iAsked);
            Console.WriteLine("------------");

            Console.WriteLine(astrQuestions[(iLocation)]);
            Console.WriteLine(astrChoices[(iLocation)]);
            Console.Write("Answer:");

            iResponse = Console.ReadLine();


            if (iResponse == astrAnswers[(iLocation)])
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Correct\n");
                iPoints += 5;
                iCorrect++;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Incorrect\n");
            }
        }
```

Comment: You can use `Events` for that.
Use radiobuttons for selecting the right answer and a seperate button to "send" the answer (wrong tap).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving from a prompting-centric environment like a console program to an event-driven environment like Winforms, yes…that definitely will require at least some change in "the nature of the loops". :)

That said, the latest version of C# offers an `async`/`await`-based approach that can minimize some of the culture-shock that might come from moving from console to GUI. Writing and using `async` method is itself non-trivial, but IMHO the simpler scenarios are not too hard to understand. More importantly, because it allows you to structure the code in a more directly-imperative way, similar to that which would be used in a console program, it's very much worth learning this along with Winforms generally.

In your particular scenario, you have two separate things you'll need to deal with: prompting the user, and receiving the user's input.

Because of the way an event-driven system works, you need to separate these tasks. But .NET has a class, `TaskCompletionSource`, which we can use to keep the two glued together, even though they wind up in different places.

First, what happens when the user starts the process? Presumably, you'll have a form, where on that form is a button (or possible a menu item) which when clicked/selected, starts the whole thing. That might look something like this:

```
private TaskCompletionSource<bool> _completionSource;

private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int[] questionIndexes = ShuffleQuestions();

    for (int iAsked = 0; iAsked < 5; iAsked++)
    {
        textBoxQuestionNumber.Text = string.Format("Question {0}", iAsked);
        textBoxQuestion.Text = astrQuestions[questionIndexes[iAsked]];
        textBoxChoices.Text = astrChoices[questionIndexes[iAsked]];

        _completionSource =
            new TaskCompletionSource<bool>(astrAnswers[questionIndexes[iAsked]]);
        button2.Enabled = true;

        bool result = await _completionSource.Task;

        MessageBox.Show(result ? "Correct" : "Incorrect");
        if (result)
        {
            iPoints += 5;
            iCorrect++;
        }
        button2.Enabled = false;
        _completionSource = null;
    }
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_completionSource != null)
    {
        _completionSource.SetResult(
            textBoxUserAnswer.Text == (string)_completionsSource.Task.AsyncState);
    }
}
```

(I have changed your question-selection logic above to something more efficient, by assuming that you have a `ShuffleQuestions()` method. See [Is using Random and OrderBy a good shuffle algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287567/is-using-random-and-orderby-a-good-shuffle-algorithm/1287572#1287572) for details on how to implement that).

What the above code does is, in response to the user clicking the `button1` button (which presumably has text like "Start" or something), executes a loop that is very similar to what you had in your console program. The two main differences are:

- Where in your console program, you use `Console.WriteLine()` to display text to the user, here I have shown the use of `TextBox` controls in your form which are used to display the same text.
- What in your console program, you use `Console.ReadLine()` to receive input from the user, this loop creates a `TaskCompletionSource` object for a completely different method to use. That method, which is executed with your `button2` button (which presumably has text like "Check Answer" or something) will read the text entered in a text box by the user (here, I've given it the name `textBoxUserAnswer`), compare it to the correct answer for the question (which has been provided to this method by the other method via the `AsyncState` property of the `Task` created by the `TaskCompletionSource` object I created), and set the `Task`'s result to `true` or `false`, depending on whether the user got the answer correct or not.

The tricky part above is that "under the hood", that first method *actually returns* as soon as it is done filling in the text for the first question and reaches the `await` statement in the loop. The compiler rewrites the entire method to facilitate this.

When `button2` is pushed, and sets the result of the `Task`, the framework then knows to resume executing the first method where it left off at the `await` statement, continuing your loop.

This sequence continues until the user has answered all of the question.

Some final notes about the UI:

- I have used `TextBox`'s everywhere for user input and output. Of course, there are other ways to display text. Also, the default state for a `TextBox` is a single-line, read/write text. But for displaying to the user, you may find that setting the `ReadOnly` property of the `TextBox` to true is better (i.e. to prevent the user from accidentally changing the text), and/or that you prefer setting the `Multiline` property to `true` (i.e. so that more than one line of text is displayed).
- The above also assumes that the initial state for the `button2` button's `Enabled` property is `false`. I.e. that button can't be clicked until the first method above explicitly enables the button at the appropriate time.

Comment: Thank you very much I used a lot of your recommendations to refine my code. I also appreciated the usage of the For loop, which I think works a lot better and makes the code easier to follow.