# How do I check for duplicates in my array?

Tags: c#, arrays, duplicates

How do I store a random number into my array, but only if there is not a duplicate already inside the array? My code below still inputs a duplicate number.

```
        Random rand = new Random();
        int[] lotto = new int [6];

        for (int i = 0; i < lotto.Length; i++)
        {
            int temp = rand.Next(1, 10);
            while (!(lotto.Contains(temp)))//While my lotto array doesn't contain a duplicate
            {
                lotto[i] = rand.Next(1, 10);//Add a new number into the array
            }
            Console.WriteLine(lotto[i]+1);
        }
```

Comment: Instead of  lotto[i] = rand.Next(1, 10);, do  lotto[i] = temp;

Comment: I still found two 1's in my output.

Comment: Oh sorry! You are right!

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int[] lotto = new int[6];

for (int i = 0; i < lotto.Length; i++)
{
    int temp = rand.Next(1, 10);

    // Loop until array doesn't contain temp
    while (lotto.Contains(temp))
    {
        temp = rand.Next(1, 10);
    }

    lotto[i] = temp;
    Console.WriteLine(lotto[i] + 1);
}
```

This way the code keeps generating a number until it finds one that isn't in the array, assigns it and moves on.

There are a lot of ways to 'shuffle' an array, but hopefully this clears up the issue you were having with your code.

Answer (score 1):

What you *really* want is to shuffle the numbers from 1 to 9 (at least that's what your example is implying) and then take the first 6 elements. Checking for duplicates is adding unnecessary indeterminism and really is not needed if you have a shuffle.

E.g take this [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1287572/329769) for a [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) and then take the first 6 elements for `lotto`.

This would then look like this:

```
lotto = Enumerable.Range(1,9)
                  .Shuffle()
                  .Take(6)
                  .ToArray();
```