# Create number for random and non repeat

Tags: c#, random, numbers

i'm code:

```
       Random rand = new Random();
       int[] arr = new int[4];
       for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
       {
           for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
           {
               int rad = rand.Next(1, 5);
               if (arr[k] != rad)
                   arr[i] = rad;
           }
       }
       for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
           MessageBox.Show(arr[i].ToString());
```

I wanna production numbers from 1 to 4 am and unequal with each other.
tnx.

Comment: create array `{1,2,3,4}` and shuffle it with another algorithm. this is common http://www.dotnetperls.com/fisher-yates-shuffle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think it the other way round:

instead of:

> generating a number ***and then*** check it if it is not duplicate

you make it such that:

> you already have a set of non-duplicate numbers, ***then*** you take it
>   one-by-one - removing the possibilities of duplicates.

Something like this will do:

```
List<int> list = Enumerable.Range(1, 4).ToList();
List<int> rndList = new List<int>();
Random rnd = new Random();
int no = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    no = rnd.Next(0, list.Count);
    rndList.Add(list[no]);
    list.Remove(list[no]);
}
```

The result is in your `rndList`.

This way, no duplicate will occur.

Comment: After running you code `rndList` contains `0, 0, 3, 0`, which is not unique as OP asked, and also generating a number and then checking for duplicate is less efficient than simple Fisher-Yates.

Comment: @IvanLeonenko corrected. It should be `list[no]` instead of `no`. Thanks for the notification. About the efficiency, I do not really have profile between them. But the Fisher Yates algorithm could be faster than my simple algorithm, as you say. My opinion is just that the algorithm I offer is quite simple and straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

Create an array with unique elements and then shuffle it, like in the code below, it will shuffle an array in uniformly random order it uses [Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle):

```
int N = 20;
var theArray = new int[N];
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    theArray[i] = i;

Shuffle(theArray);

public static void Shuffle(int[] a) {
    if (a == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("Array is null");
    int n = a.Length;
    var theRandom = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int r = i + theRandom.Next(n-i);     // between i and n-1
        int temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[r];
        a[r] = temp;
    }
}
```

Explanation and template version of algorithm could be found [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287567/is-using-random-and-orderby-a-good-shuffle-algorithm) with nice answer from Jon Skeet.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Shuffle<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Random rng)
{
    T[] elements = source.ToArray();
    // Note i > 0 to avoid final pointless iteration
    for (int i = elements.Length-1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        // Swap element "i" with a random earlier element it (or itself)
        int swapIndex = rng.Next(i + 1);
        T tmp = elements[i];
        elements[i] = elements[swapIndex];
        elements[swapIndex] = tmp;
    }
    // Lazily yield (avoiding aliasing issues etc)
    foreach (T element in elements)
    {
        yield return element;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a list containing the numbers you want, then shuffle them:

```
var rnd = new Random();
List<int> rndList = Enumerable.Range(1, 4).OrderBy(r => rnd.Next()).ToList();
```

If you want an array instead of a list:

```
var rnd = new Random();
int[] rndArray = Enumerable.Range(1, 4).OrderBy(r => rnd.Next()).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks.
 I do not wanna I use from the list .
 I wanna do the right array .
Because I have a game right

Comment: @user5566530 Updated for an array as well

Comment: I know this approach works, but I always hate seeing O(N Log(N)) algorithms being proposed when an O(N) one exists.

Comment: This implementation is  O(n log n) and the one I gave is O(n). Also this implementation doesn't give you uniformly random order. Please see explanation in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287567/is-using-random-and-orderby-a-good-shuffle-algorithm

Answer (score -2):

```
int[] arr = new int[5];
int i = 0;
while (i < 5)
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    int a = rand.Next(1,6);

    bool alreadyexist = false;
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {

        if (a == arr[j])
        {
            alreadyexist = true;
        }

    }
    if (alreadyexist == false)
    {
        arr[i] = a;
        i++;
    }

}
for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++)
{

    MessageBox.Show(arr[k].ToString());
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't create Random each iteration it could give the same order and values if it happens too frequently. Complexity is above linear, especially with such implementation when you create Random object too frequently. Also this implementation doesn't give you uniformly random order, use at least Fisher-Yates. This answer should not be accepted.

Comment: Thanks.
But this answer and the answer I was helped in my project

Comment: Why did you change this question from answerd to non answerd after @user5566530