# VB.NET; Index error with randomly generated list

Tags: vb.net, list, hough-transform

My goal here is to create a list of a certain size and randomly select 3 points from that list. Once a point is selected, it is deleted from the list so it won't be selected again. **My problem is the debugger is saying I've got an index out of the range of the list**. I'm relatively new to VB.NET, but am pretty experienced with VBA. Thank you in advance for your help.

```
Private Sub Analyze_Click(ByVal Sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Analyze_Image.Click

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, Image_Width As Long, Image_Height As Long, Pixel_Count As Long, Pixel As Long
    Dim My_Image As Image
    Dim RandomClass As New Random()
    Dim RandomIndex_1 As Long, RandomIndex_2 As Long, RandomIndex_3 As Long
    Dim P1 As Point, P2 As Point, P3 As Point

    My_Image = My_PictureBox.Image
    Image_Width = My_Image.Width
    Image_Height = My_Image.Height
    Pixel_Count = Image_Width * Image_Height

    Dim Numbers = Enumerable.Range(0, Pixel_Count + 1).ToList()

    For Pixel = 1 To Pixel_Count
        RandomIndex_1 = RandomClass.Next(0, Numbers.Count)
        Numbers.RemoveAt(RandomIndex_1)
        RandomIndex_2 = RandomClass.Next(0, Numbers.Count)
        Numbers.RemoveAt(RandomIndex_2)
        RandomIndex_3 = RandomClass.Next(0, Numbers.Count)
        Numbers.RemoveAt(RandomIndex_3)

        i = Numbers(RandomIndex_1)
        j = Numbers(RandomIndex_2)
        k = Numbers(RandomIndex_3)

        If i Mod Image_Width = 0 Then
            P1.X = Image_Width
        Else
            P1.X = i Mod Image_Width
        End If
        If j Mod Image_Width = 0 Then
            P2.X = Image_Width
        Else
            P2.X = j Mod Image_Width
        End If
        If k Mod Image_Width = 0 Then
            P3.X = Image_Width
        Else
            P3.X = k Mod Image_Width
        End If
        If ((i - i Mod Image_Width) / Image_Width) + 1 = Image_Height + 1 Then
            P1.Y = Image_Height
        Else
            P1.Y = ((i - i Mod Image_Width) / Image_Width) + 1
        End If
        If ((j - j Mod Image_Width) / Image_Width) + 1 = Image_Height + 1 Then
            P2.Y = Image_Height
        Else
            P2.Y = ((j - j Mod Image_Width) / Image_Width) + 1
        End If
        If ((k - k Mod Image_Width) / Image_Width) + 1 = Image_Height + 1 Then
            P3.Y = Image_Height
        Else
            P3.Y = ((k - k Mod Image_Width) / Image_Width) + 1
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: It would probably be helpful to indicate which line throws the exception, but it looks like you are removing items from the list (`Numbers.RemoveAt(RandomIndex_1)`) and then trying to read them (`i = Numbers(RandomIndex_1)`).

Comment: It also looks like you need `3 * Pixel_Count` items in your `Number` list?

Comment: Surprisingly simple fixes, I don't know where my brain is today. Made both of those changes and it's working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the comments on the question, you could simplify the logic somewhat by using a randomly sorted stack of numbers (however, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287567/is-using-random-and-orderby-a-good-shuffle-algorithm) for a discussion about better ways to shuffle the list):

```
Dim Numbers = New Stack(
    Enumerable.Range(0, 3 * Pixel_Count) _
        .OrderBy(Function(i) RandomClass.Next()) _
        .ToList()
)
```

Your loop can then just pop numbers off the stack:

```
For Pixel = 1 To Pixel_Count
    i = Numbers.Pop()
    j = Numbers.Pop()
    k = Numbers.Pop()

    If i Mod Image_Width = 0 Then
        '... etc.
Next
```