# How to guarantee the size of a list using a loop in C#?

Tags: c#, list, random

Simply put, I want mylist to contain 7 unique numbers and I wrote the code below for that purpose.

However, it does not do the job and I get fewer unique numbers (mostly only 5 and sometimes 7) when deletion becomes necessary after I get a roll violating uniqueness.

Basically, I want a loop that keeps working and rolling random numbers within a specified range until a string of 7 unique numbers is observed. Of course, it should also put that desired string into a list.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Random number = new Random();

        List<int> mylist = new List<int>();
        int i = mylist.Count;


        while(i<7)
        {
            int selected = number.Next(50);

            if (mylist.Contains(selected))
            { mylist.Remove(selected); }
            else
            {
                mylist.Add(selected);
            }

            i++;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Amount:"+ mylist.Count);

        foreach (int item in mylist)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: You should be checking the loop with `while (mylist.Count < 7) instead of `i`.

Comment: @RonBeyer it actually worked.. But, I do not understand.. i IS mylist.Count ? Clearly, there is something that I still don't see.

Comment: `i` is only equal to `mylist.Count` the first time you assign it. When you remove an item from the list, you increment `i`. If you want to keep it in sync, you should be subtracting one from it when you remove, and only adding to it when you add to the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to remove items from the list.  Simply don't add duplicate values.  Then you can simplify this to something like:

```
Random number = new Random();
List<int> mylist = new List<int>();

while (mylist.Count < 7)
{
    int selected = number.Next(50);

    if (!mylist.Contains(selected))
    {
        mylist.Add(selected);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think "if (!mylist.Contains(selected)" translates into if my list does not contain 'selected'. I did not know I could do that - very new to programming :) Thank you.

Comment: Yes that's right.  If my list does not contain `selected` then add it to the list. In plain english, only add to the list if the value isn't already there.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a trick: Whenever you need uniqueness, you can flip the randomization procedure to generate the unique numbers *first*, then randomize the *order*.

For example, this gives you a list of random numbers between 1 and 25 without any repetition:

```
var number = new Random();
var list = Enumerable.Range(1,25).OrderBy( i => number.NextDouble() );
```

Comment: How do you print the number in that case?

Comment: @Larx you'd use proper shuffle from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1287572/477420 and use `.Take(7)` of the `Shuffle<T>`.