# How to mess up an array in C#?

Tags: c#, list, sorting, random, methods

I have a question with the  `List<>` datatype in C#. I have a List of colors (`List<Color> colores`) in a program that I am doing in Windows Forms, but I want that everytime that start the program this **list mess up it of random form**. I am searching a method as `colores.Disort()` but this doesn't exist.

Any ideas?

My array to disort is:

```
Color[] colores = new Color[] { 
    Color.FromArgb(128, 128, 255),
    Color.FromArgb(255, 128, 128),
    Color.FromArgb(255, 192, 128),
    Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 128),
    Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 128),
    Color.MediumPurple};
```

PD: I don't want a method of multiple lines, just a short method. The colors shouldn't repeat it.

Thanks you for your time!

Comment: i'm assuming that by "mess up it of random form", you mean to assign random values to each colour in the list?

Comment: You can write everything in one line if you find that more readable

Comment: Do you mean **shuffle**? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

Comment: So, you want to shuffle the list, is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var rnd = new Random();
var randomColors = colores.OrderBy(color => rnd.Next());
```

**Please consider reading SO Post about effectiveness of this method.**

[Is using Random and OrderBy a good shuffle algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287567/is-using-random-and-orderby-a-good-shuffle-algorithm)

Comment: This code is great but there is an inconvenient. The color repeat it.

Comment: It's not supposed to happen, pay attention that your example adds the same color twice...

Comment: Yes I am sorry, thanks