# Strange bitwise XOR behavior

Tags: bit-manipulation

Why would the following "swap" action fail at random times?

```
int i,p,a[11] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };

srand(time(0));

for (i=0;i<11;i++)
{
    p = rand() % 11;
    a[i] = a[i] ^ a[p];
    a[p] = a[i] ^ a[p];
    a[i] = a[i] ^ a[p];
}
```

It is not so different from the the logic in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11316582/15161)
It will work for a 3/4 runs and then start to duplicate 0

Tried it in C and C++, same results

[edit]
Solved by initializing `p=0` and replacing the relevant line with `while (p==i) p = rand() % 11;`

**Update:** The [reason NOT to use](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm#Reasons_for_avoidance_in_practice) `xor` (see [Mark Byers' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11317796/15161) and comment)

Comment: Your shuffling is biased, btw. This is not a fair shuffle.

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375351/most-efficient-way-to-randomly-sort-shuffle-a-list-of-integers-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `p` happens to be the same as `i`, then `a[i] ^ a[p]` will be zero, and the rest of the function fails.

Statistically, your code actually has a 65% chance of failing in this way.

Make sure that, when generating `p`, it is not the same number as `i`. For instance:

```
p = rand() % 10;
if( p >= i) p++;
```

Comment: or check `i == p` before swapping.

Comment: @KennyTM: done that, thanks. Even stranger is that I debugged and watched the values but it didn't register :( - break-time and stop coding till tomorrow for me now.

Answer (score 5):

When `i` equals `p` then `a[i] ^ a[p]`  becomes zero. Your "swap" operation is broken.

To swap you should use a temporary variable:

```
int temp = a[i];
a[i] = a[p];
a[p] = temp;
```

Don't use the XOR hack.

Comment: Just read that div-by-2 question, so I won't take your statement (/command ;) lightly: why should I avoid using this "hack"?

Comment: @slashmais: Because it can break for exactly the reason you demonstrated. Yes you can fix it, but if you had swapped the variables the normal way, you wouldn't have needed to fix it in the first place. Also see Wikipedia: [Reasons for avoidance in practice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm#Reasons_for_avoidance_in_practice). One of the reasons stated there is that the normal swap is faster.

Answer (score 1):

Because `p` is randomly equal to `i`. In this case, `a[i]` instantly becomes 0.

Answer (score 1):

If `i == p` then `a[i]` will store `0`.

Answer (score 1):

As an development practice, XOR swaping is not recommended. But if you are using logic for fun then use this line which will ensure that p will not same as i.

```
p = ((rand()%10)+(i+1))%11;
```

or

```
p = ((rand()%(count-1))+(i+1))%count;
```

But notice this trick is not good for performance perspective because it requires two modules operator and one addition (or subtraction). Use the exact comparison (which is the fastest comparison operator) and add 1 if they same.

```
p = rand()%10;
if (p == i) p++;
```