# C# Shuffle a list of strings

Tags: c#, arrays, list, shuffle

I am new to C# and I want to shuffle around my list of strings so no value is input twice and all values are shuffled.
So far I have this code

```
private List<string> myCards = List<string> 
{
    "AC", "AS", "AD", "AH",
    "2C", "2S", "2D", "2H",
    "3C", "3S", "3D", "3H",
    "4C", "4S", "4D", "4H",
    "5C", "5S", "5D", "5H",
    "6C", "6S", "6D", "6H",
    "7C", "7S", "7D", "7H",
    "8C", "8S", "8D", "8H",
    "9C", "9S", "9D", "9H",
    "10C", "10S", "10D", "10H", 
    "KC", "KS", "KD", "KH",
    "QC", "QS", "QD", "QH",
    "JC", "JS", "JD", "JH"
};
```

Cheers

Comment: You need to do some research (search SO for instance). Then write some code and come back when you have a specific problem

Comment: So far your code is just a list... Not good enough to ask question.

Comment: Aka: you have no code. That's like writing your name on your test and expecting your teacher to grade you for it. It literally takes 1 line, +- 20 characters to do what you want. Google, it has been answered a lot on SO already.

Comment: [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150646/card-shuffling-in-c-sharp) may be of use to you

Comment: Use the Fisher-Yates shuffle. Here's the [code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt-in-c-sharp/1262619#1262619)

Comment: ^That and a linq distinct.tolist should be enough if i'm correct...

Comment: There really is no need to implement an entire algorithm, look at answer number 2.

Answer (score 1):

You want to remove duplicates and shuffle?

Install [Extended Random](http://www.nuget.org/packages/ExtendedRandom/) from NuGet*, import `ExtendedRandom` and `System.Linq`, then:

```
ExtendedRandom.Random.Shuffle(myCards.Distinct())
```

* I'm the maintainer of that NuGet package

Comment: This project is dead. Use `ListShuffle` from NuGet instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something simple like ordering them randomly using linq.

```
var shuffled = myCards.Distinct().OrderBy(x =>  System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString()).ToList();
```

implementing it as a method is simple too.

```
public List<string> Shuffle(List<string> items)
{
  return items.Distinct().OrderBy(x =>  System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString()).ToList();
}
```