# Quickest way to generate a sequence of consecutive numbers in a random order

Tags: c#, list, random

Whats the quickest way to generate a list of consecutive numbers in a random order?

i.e. generate a list of numbers from 1 to 100, the list must contain each number once only. The order of the list should be random.

java or c# please.

my pseudocode looks like this, very inefficient.

```
 var list = new list<int>();
 for (int i = 1; i <= 100; ++i) {
     int x;
     repeat {
         x = random(1, 100);
     until (list.contains(x) == false);
     list.add(x);
 }
```

Comment: The usual solution is to generate an ordered array then scramble it.

Comment: `List<int> list = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToList();` and then shuffle it like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @Habib This is not random ordered.

Comment: @Tarec, yes, just posted it because those will be the only numbers possible in the list.

Comment: You're looking for the Fisher-Yates algorithm.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150646/card-shuffling-in-c-sharp

Comment: You just gotta try hard enough and once in a while the order will be 1 to 100.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/273313/1284902

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's teribly inefficient and it's not even bounded in time.

The usual solution is

1. generate an ordered array
2. shuffle it (I'd recommend the [Fisher–Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle), it's simple, fast, unbiased and you'll find an implementation in any language)