# Program is comparing and working correctly for every array entry except array[0]

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to generate the numbers 1-7 in random order and add them to array. My code is supposed to generate the number, check the number generated to see if it is in the array already, and if not then add the number to the array. The only array location that is not functioning appropriately is n[0]. I have been trying hard to solve the issue but I am stuck, any help would be greatly appreciated. The last 3 times I ran the program I got:

```
3, 1, 5, 2, 3, 4, 7
6, 1, 3, 7, 5, 2, 6
5, 1, 7, 3, 6, 2, 5
```

Here is the code to generate a random number

```
int * randomize()
{
  static int n[7];
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;
  int check = 0;
  int check2;

  srand((unsigned)time( NULL ));
  for( i = 0; i < 7; i++)
  {
    check = (rand() % 7);
    check += 1;

        for( j = 0; j < 7; j++)
        {
            check2 = (int) n[j];

            if(check == check2)
            {
                check = (rand() % 7);
                check += 1;
                j = 0;
            }       
        }  

      n[i] = check;
      j = 0;
    }   
return n;
}
```

And here is the code to call the function from main and print the array

```
int *r;

r = randomize();

for( i = 0; i < 7; i++){
    printf("%i\n", *(r + i));
}
```

Comment: Side note: it is generally better to just fill array with 1-7 and than shuffle, also for small number of entries filling out last couple elements will not take forever... Here is C# sample http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150646/card-shuffling-in-c-sharp, but answer should be readable for anyone remotely aware of c-style syntax.

Comment: Not related to your issue, but why the cast here `check2 = (int) n[j];`?

Comment: I included the check2 = (int) n[ j ] part was something I included while trying to troubleshoot the issue. I thought maybe it just wasn't comparing things accurately because I was trying to compare incompatible types. I narrowed it down after that to the problem just being with n[ 0 ] but did not change it back yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(check == check2)
{
    check = (rand() % 7);
    check += 1;
    j = 0;
}
```

To restart the inner loop you set `j` to 0. When the loop goes to the next iteration `j++` increments it to 1. This causes it to skip the first index. Change the assignment to:

```
j = -1;
```

If this seems a bit hacky, I agree, it is. I would suggest rearranging things a bit so you don't have to do this. The logic could be, for instance:

```
for (i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
    bool dupe = false;

    do {
        n[i] = random(7) + 1;

        for (j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
            if (n[i] == n[j]) {
                dupe = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    while (dupe);
}
```

Or, better yet, even, don't generate random numbers and then check if there are duplicates. Instead, generate all the numbers in order and then [scramble the list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). This will be much faster without the slowdown that will occur as the list gets fuller and fuller and it takes longer and longer to find available numbers.

Comment: Good answer, but note that OP is performing shuffle which generally done as shuffle :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I like the idea of just scrambling the list, that should help with execution speed and solve my problem.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is here:

```
if(check == check2)
{
    check = (rand() % 7);
    check += 1;
    j = 0;
}
```

If a match is found, `check` is regenerated as a random number, but the `for` loop increments `j` by 1.

A trivial fix would be to assign `-1` to `j` here, but it seems better to rewrite the logic instead. You can use a do-while loop with a boolean flag.

Also, note that the `for(j ...)` loop should really loop up to `i`, not 7. Otherwise you'll be comparing with values that aren't initialised.

Finally, a few points that your code can improve on, despite not being related to your current issue:

Change your

```
check = (rand() % 7);
check += 1;
```

to

```
check = rand() % 7 + 1;
```

You don't need two lines to do it, and (in my opinion) it makes your code less readable.

Also, `srand()` should be called at program start-up and called once only. Assuming you plan on calling `randomize()` multiple times, you should move the `srand()` call outside `randomize()`.

And in your loop, you don't actually need a `check2` variable. You can change the `if` condition to `if(check == n[j])`. If you really want to make another variable, don't call it `check2` - call it something more different than your other variable. It will make your code a lot more understandable by others.

And in your output loop:

```
for( i = 0; i < 7; i++){
    printf("%i\n", *(r + i));
}
```

Although it is completely correct, I personally find using `r[i]` a lot more readable than `*(r + i)`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and all of the advice.

Comment: @Shaine You're welcome. Note that here on Stack Overflow, the question asker is expected to choose an accepted answer (by pressing the green check mark next to an answer) if the question is solved. When there are more than one answer you can choose the one that helps you the most. I recommend accepting JohnKugelman's answer since it mentions shuffling.